# Quando usar hífen?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, hífen

Vejo muito o uso do hífen ou até ligação, no entanto não sei em que situações do novo acordo ortográfico mudou.

Quando devo usar o hífen para ligar duas palavras e quando devo junta-las?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Como regra, com o [Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa de 1990](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=acordo&version=1990) (AO),  as palavras com prefixos levam hífen, se as letras forem iguais, como "ant**i**-**i**nfecioso" ou "ant**i**-**i**nfeccioso", e não se separa o prefixo se as letras forem diferentes, como em "antimatéria". Na nova grafia, se o prefixo terminar em vogal e o elemento da composição que lhe segue começar por `<r>` ou `<s>`, a consoante deverá ser dobrada, como em "mini**ss**aia", em vez de "mini-saia", na grafia pré-acordo.

A hifenização é tratada com alguma extensão no AO, ocupando três das suas bases, a XV, XVI e XVII. Transcrevo parcialmente os [Critérios de aplicação do Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa (1990)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=vop&&page=crit2), na parte relevante:

> **Palavras com prefixos e radicais de composição**
>
> Os prefixos e radicais de composição (elementos não autónomos como
>   *mini-* ou *agro-*) **não** são por princípio geral separados por meio de
>   hífen das palavras a que se juntam: *antirrevolucionário*, *megaconcerto*,
>   *minissaia*, *socioeconómico*, *ultraligeiro*.
>
> O hífen é usado após estes elementos quando:
>
> - a palavra a que se juntam começa pela letra `<h>`, exceto no caso de palavras formadas com prefixos átonos como *`des-`*, *`in-`* e *`re-`* que já se
>     justapunham, antes da aplicação do AO, sem hífen: *anti-histamínico*,
>     *contra-harmónico*, (...) (mas
>     *desumano*, (...));
> - a letra com que terminam é a mesma com que se inicia a palavra a que se juntam, exceto no caso de prefixos como *`co-`*, *`pre-`* e *`pro-`*,
>     prefixos átonos, que já se justapunham, antes da aplicação do AO, sem
>     hífen: *arqui-inimigo*, *micro-ondas*, mas *cooperação*, *preencher*;
> - terminam por `<n>` ou `<m>` e palavra a que se juntam começa com uma dessas consoantes ou com vogal: *circum-adjacência*, *pan-nacional*;
> - terminam por `<b>` ou `<d>` e a sua aglutinação provoque uma leitura que não reflita a pronúncia da palavra: *ad-rogar*, *sub-regulamentar*;
> - são *`sota-`*, *`soto-`*, *`vice-`*, *`vizo-`*, *`grão-`*, *`grã-`* ou *`ex-`* (com sentido de anterioridade): *vice-presidente*, (...);
> - são acentuados graficamente: *pré-reforma*, *pós-verbal*;
> - a palavra a que se juntam é um estrangeirismo, um nome próprio ou uma sigla: *anti-apartheid*, *anti-Europa*, *mini-GPS*.
>
> **Locuções**
>
> As locuções substantivas escrevem-se por princípio geral **sem** hífen
>   (mantendo separados por espaço os seus elementos). (...): dia a
>   dia, cor de vinho, fim de semana. (...) Por lhes ser feita referência explícita no texto do AO, são registadas no VOP [Vocabulário Ortográfico do Português] com hífen as seguintes exceções: *arco-da-velha*, *água-de-colónia*, *cor-de-rosa*, *mais-que-perfeito* e *pé-de-meia*. Para todas elas o VOP assume como também aceitáveis variantes (não preferenciais) sem hífen.
>
> Constituem exceção à regra geral, sendo os seus elementos sempre
>   unidos por hífen, os nomes que designem espécies zoológicas e
>   botânicas: *bico-de-papagaio* (flor), (...), mas *bico
>   de papagaio* (espondilose), (...).
>
> **Verbo *haver* seguido de preposição *de***
>
> **Elimina-se** a ligação por meio de hífen das formas monossilábicas do
>   verbo haver à preposição `de`: *hei de*, *hás de*, *há de*, *hão de*.

--

Portal da Língua Portuguesa: http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org

Answer (score 2):

Estuando sobre o assunto li no livro de Almeida(2009) uma explicação excelente e fiz um pequeno resumo para acrescentar mais uma resposta a essa questão.

**Os caso de emprego do hífen são:**

a) usa-se hífen na maioria dos substantivos e adjetivos compostos cujos elementos têm acentuação própria e **formam uma unidade significativa**: *guarda-civil, conta-gotas etc;*

b) nos compostos designativos de **espécies botânicas ou zoológicas**: *couve-flor, erva-doce, beija-flor, tico-tico, joão-de-barro etc;*

c) nas **onomatopeias** que reproduzem sons repetidos: *zum-zum, zigue-zague, tim-tim, cri-cri etc;*

d) nos **topônimos compostos** iniciados pelos adjetivos **grã, grão** ou forma verbal, ou cujos elementos estejam ligados por artigo: *Grã-Bretânia, Grão-Pará, Passa-Quatro etc;*

e) nas palavras formadas pelos sufixos -açu, -guaçu ou mirim, desde que o primeiro elemento termine com vogal acentuada graficamente ou nasalizada: *araçá-guaçu, tamanduá-mirim, jacaré-mirim etc;*

f) palavras formadas com advérbios mal e bem quando esses elementos formam uma unidade sintagmática com significado e o segundo começa por vogal ou h: *bem-amado, bem-estar, bem-humorado, mal-alinhado etc;*

g) nas palavras formadas com os prefixos além-, aquém-, recém- e sem-: *além-mar, aquém-fronteira, recém-formado, sem-teto etc.*

h) nas palavras com prefixos **ex-, soto-, sota-, vice- e vizo-**: *ex-diretor, sota-capitão, vice-diretor, soto-mestre etc;*

i) nas palavras formadas com os prefixos circum- e pan-, desde que o segundo elemento comece com vogal, m ou n: *circum-adjacente, circum-navegação, pan-americano etc.*

j) nas palavras formadas com os prefixos inter-, hiper- e super-, desde que seguidos de palavras iniciadas por **h** ou **r**: *inter-helênico, hiper-hidrose, hiper-humano, super-homem etc;*

k) nas palavras formadas com prefixos tônicos **pré**-, **pró**- e **pós** seguidos de palavras de vida autônomas na língua: *pré-escolar, pré-natal, pós-graduação, pró-educação etc;*

l) nas palavras formadas com prefixo **sub-** diante de palavras indicadas com **b**, **r** ou **h**: *sub-base, sub-região, sub-hidroclorato etc*.

m) nas palavras em que os prefixos ou pseudoprefixos antecedem palavras iniciadas com **h** ou com letra idêntica à que encerra esses elementos: *ante-histórico, anti-horário, mini-hotel, infra-assinado, extra-abdominal, tele-educação, eletro-ótica etc.*

**Não se emprega o hífen**

a) nas palavras em que o prefixo ou falso prefixo termina com vogal e o segundo elemento começa com **s** ou **r**, casos em que essas consoantes devem se duplicar: *antessala, antessépalo, antessentir, antirreumático etc;*

b) nas palavras em que o prefixo ou falso prefixo termina com vogal e o segundo elemento começa com letra diferente: *aerobalística, aerobarco, antediluviano, radiotáxi etc;*

c) nas palavras formadas pelos prefixo **co-** e **re-**, mesmo que diante de palavras iniciadas, respectivamente, por **o** e **e**: *cooperar, cooperação, reembolsar, reeducar etc.*

**Fonte:**
ALMEIDA, Nilson Teixeira de. Gramática da Língua Portuguesa. 9 ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009

Comment: Deinis, não ficou claro para mim se estas regras estão de acordo com o atual acordo ortográfico ou dizem respeito à grafia anterior. Acho que valia a pena clarificar. O hífen foi sempre das coisas mais complicadas para  mim.

Comment: Estão de acordo com o atual acordo ortográfico.