# Quando não utilizar o hífen?

Tags: hífen

Com a leitura de vários textos relativamente antigos em livros e livros mais atuais, vi que algumas palavras sofreram mudanças quanto ao uso do **hífen**.

De acordo com as novas regras ortográficas, em que ocasiões não devo mais utilizar o hífen?

Existe alguma regra básica para a utilização dele da forma correta?

Comment: Isso vai dar pano pra manga

Comment: Duplicata de http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/46/quando-usar-hífen (por 2 minutos)?

Comment: Manter uma pergunta "quando usar" e outra "quando não usar" é uma grande má ideia. É possível formular uma resposta que responda aos dois casos. Passemos para [Quando usar hífen?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/46/quando-usar-h%C3%ADfen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O hífen não é mais utilizado em palavras formadas de prefixos terminados em vogal + palavras iniciadas por outra vogal.

> **Exemplos**
>   Autoaprendizagem, autoescola, autoestrada, autoinstrução, contraexemplo, contraindicação, contraordem, extraescolar, extraoficial e infraestrutura.

O hífen foi inserido em palavras formadas por um prefixo (ou falso prefixo) terminado em vogal + palavra iniciada pela mesma vogal.

> **Exemplos**
>   Anti-inflamatório, anti-inflacionário, arqui-inimigo, micro-ondas, micro-ônibus, etc.

Comment: Gostaria de saber por que o hífen foi inserido em anti-inflamatório e micro-ondas, sendo que antiinflamatório e microondas funcionavam perfeitamente bem... Mas olhando outras perguntas deste site, esse nível de detalhe na motivação das decisões geralmente é perdido na história, que nem me animo em criar uma pergunta nova...