# How do I know how to pronounce an "exa-" prefix (e.g. hexágono, exabyte, exame)?

Tags: tradução, pronúncia, escrita, prefixos

According to [thefreedictionary, Numerical Prefixes](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/numerical+prefix) seem to have come from Latin or Greek, but in Portuguese if you read "exa" it should sound like an *esha* (e.g. "oxalá" is pronounced as *oshalah*). Notice that the **x** in Portuguese seems to only have the *gz* sound in these cases (when there is an "exa" prefix, not when it belongs to the word itself, as in "exame").

However, Portuguese people pronounce "exa" as English people pronounce "exa", which has the **exact same sound**.

Therefore, why the prefix wasn't changed to the letters that most closely resemble it's real sound in Portuguese: **ècsa** or **egza**?

Examples:

- *exabyte* could be written in Portuguese as [*écsabaite*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/exabyte) or *égzabaite*
- *hexagon* could be written as [egzágono](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hex%C3%A1gono)
- *exame* could be written as [*ezame*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/exame) (notice that there is no "exa" prefix)
- *exa* could be [egza](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hexa-)

Comment: _"However, Portuguese people pronounce "exa" as English people pronounce "hexa""_ Do you mean Portuguese people pronounce the H, even though it's not written?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I was focusing more in the _gz_ sound (why was the **x** used instead), but that's a good point as well. It seems the **h** may be perceptible when people pronounce the *he*.

Comment: Are you trying to say that usually the X in Portuguese is either [(g)z] or [ʃ] but usually never [ks] (unvoiced version of [gz])? Maybe you can put all _sounds_ into square brackets (see [IPA for Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Portuguese)), because it's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking why "hexabyte" wasn't _transliterated_ as égzabaite, or are you asking why "hexabyte" isn't _pronounced_ as [e**gz**abaite]?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I edited my question to clarify it better :)

Comment: Confusion in my head...

Comment: Your question holds false assumptions, as already mentioned. We do not always pronounce _hexágono_ like "hegzágono".

Answer (score 14):

## Phonetics

Your assumption about the expected *regular* sound of x is wrong.

We have [many different sounds for x](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/X) in Portuguese:

- `z` (/z/) - "exame", same as **z**ebra in English;
- `cs` (/ks/) - "táxi", same as ta**x**i in English;
- `ch` (/ʃ/) - "deixa", same as gei**sh**a in English;
- `ss` (/s/) - "máximo", same as ma**ss**ing in English;

## Invalid alternative spellings

You could not write `écsabaite`, `egzágono` or `egza` because "ec", "csa", "eg", or "gza" are not valid syllables in Portuguese.
Those words cannot be split into valid syllables.

Comment: _exame_ is not pronounced the same as the English word _exam_ in PT-PT.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) I was focusing in the usage of a common prefix ("exa") to many different languages, English included (I edited my question to reflect that). _Exame_, _táxi_, _deixa_ and _máximo_ are nice examples on how many ways **x** can be pronounced. Which is puzzling and hard for foreigners to learn. But since it seems there are new words being created as the language as changed, like in the [words collapsed for not having an **-**](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/393/156) (infr**aes**trutura, aut**oin**strução, Aut**oap**rendizagem, etc.). Why not **ecs** (e.g. _emacs_)?

Comment: @E_net4 of course not! Corrected, thanks.

Comment: This is the right answer: that there are many ways of pronouncing it depending on the word. Many examples in the article [Como se pronuncia o X](https://lusopatia.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/como-se-pronuncia-o-x/).  I especially liked that they indicate that *ex-* plus a consonant is /eis/, since as you rightly point out, /eks/ and /egs/ are not valid Portuguese syllables. *Sexta-feira* is a good, everyday example.

Comment: @tchrist yes "sexta-feira" sounds like "seista-feira"

Comment: @JorgeB. well, only in Portugal, and even then only in the Lisbon region. I actually think that for most of the country "sexta" e "cesta" are read the same way. And it's not true that words starting with the syllable /ex/ are pronounced /eis/, that's an emphatic pronunciation that no one (in Lisboa, at least) uses regularly. The normal way of pronouncing an initial /ex/ is /ɨʃ/, generally with the mute "e" omitted.

Comment: @tchrist ^^ (in separate comment due to stupid stackexchange rules)

Comment: @Artefacto here in Braga we read "sexta" or "sexto" like "seis"(6) + "ta".

Comment: @JorgeB. Hmm, se calhar é só nos dialetos meridionais, então. _sexta_ e _cesta_ são pelo menos homófonas no Sotavento algarvio (lidas ambas com ê), e _seis_ é lido /sejʃ/, não /sɐjʃ/ (tal como me parece que é no Brasil, tirando o /ʃ/ final).

Comment: @Artefacto no Brasil até acho que não leem muito 6 é "meia"

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me your assumption that

> in Portuguese if you read "exa" it should sound like an esha (e.g.
>   "oxalá" is pronounced as oshalah).

isn't correct. I can think of a few words containing *exa* that are pronounced the same way as *hexágono*, like [exato](http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/exato) (and its variants like *exatamente*, *exatidão*), [examinar](http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/examinar), *exalar* (the free dictionary has no entry for that word, only for [exalar cheiro](http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/exalar+cheiro)).

Perhaps a more adequate question would be "How do I know how to pronounce *exa-* prefix?".

Comment: Exactly! I'm going to change my question to that, if you don't mind :)

Comment: Gmauch, tenho uma dúvida sobre a pronúncia do **x** no Brasil. Em _explicar_ é **ch** como em _lixo_ ou **s** de _sapo_? E em _ex-marido_ é **j** de _jarro_ ou **z** de _zona_? No Rio creio que é **ch** e **j**, certo?

Comment: @Jacinto, eu vivo no Sul do Brasil, então minha opinião reflete o modo local de falar. Em ambos termos _explicar_ e _ex-marido_ o _x_ soa como _s_. Ao iniciar falando _ex_ eu não tenho como, apenas de ouvido, determinar se comecei a falar  _explicar_ ou _ex-marido_. Ao ouvir um carioca falando, fico com a impressão de que o que eu pronunciaria como _s_ é pronunciado como _ch_ e por vezes noto a adição de um _i_ antes do _s_. Assim sendo, um carioca contaria os números assim: um, doix, treix e diria, creio eu, e**ich**plicar e e**ich**-marido.

Comment: Era o que eu queria saber, obrigado. Eu sabia que os cariocas chiam o **s** como os portugueses, enquanto na maior parte do resto do Brasil o **s** é mesmo **s**. Não tinha a certeza se era a mesma coisa com o **x** de _explicar, texto_, etc.

Comment: Mas eu iria apostar que tu dizes ezmarido, mezmo, etc. Podes ver a razão [nesta resposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan/1083#1083)

Comment: @Jacinto É possível que a pronúncia seja como disseste. Apesar de eu não ser especialista no assunto, a resposta indicada explica muito bem a pronúncia do _s_. O Portuguese SE me mostra cada vez mais as diferenças entre pt_br e pt_pt que eu desconhecia!

Comment: Ahhh só que neste caso não é pt_br versus pt_br. É pt_pt + carioca versus pt_Resto do BR. Fizeste o teste com os dedos na garganta? Eu explico o teste melhor num resposta com link na que viste agora.

Answer (score 3):

The letter **x** is very versatile indeed, and takes quite a few sounds in Portuguese. Here are a few rules as to how it sounds, which will cover quite a few, maybe most, words.

Letters **ex** followed by consonant: in Portugal and Rio the **x** sounds **ʃ** as in *a**sh**amed* if followed by unvoiced consonant (as in *explicar*) and **Ʒ** as in *plea**s**ure* if followed by a voiced consonant (as in *ex-marido*). Elsewhere in Brazi the **x** generally sounds **s** insteas of **ʃ** and **z** instead of **Ʒ**. These are actually the rules that also apply to the pronunciation of the letter **s** when followed by consonant. You can see a [question and answers on this topic here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan) and learn a [simple test to identify voiced and unvoiced consonants here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade/1072#1072). Bu If you don’t know about voiced and unvoiced consonants don´t worry: your vocal system will automatically take care of that for you.

Words starting with **maxi** like *maxilar, maximal*: **ks** as *ma**x**imum*, with at least on exception: in *máximo* the sound is **s** as in *cla**ss**mate*.

Words with the suffix **ixo** or **ixa** and derivations, like *prolixo, prolixamente*: **ks** again.

Words starting with **ex** followed by vowel like *exame, existir, exoesqueleto*: **z** as in *ma**z**e. This includes words with the prefix *exo* that you mention (comes from Greek, meaning out, outside).

Words starting with **hexa** (meaning *six*). Now for the surprise. [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/hex%C3%A1gono) gives both **z** and **gz** as possible pronunciations! Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa gives **gz** as the only pronunciation. But — I’m with the other native speakers here. I don’t recall having heard any such word pronounced with a **gz**, and I certainly don’t do it myself.

The words above mostly came late into the Portuguese language from Latin and Greek. Most other words with **x** in it (unless I’m forgetting an important class) are older and more everyday words, and the **x** sounds **ʃ**. Most words. There are lots of exptions.