# Como se pronunciam «transexual», «transiberiano» e «transubstanciação»?

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia

Eu toda a vida pronunciei e julgo que ouvi os outros pronunciar /tɾɐ̃ʃsɛˈkswaɫ/, /tɾɐ̃ʃsibəˈrjɐnu/ e  /tɾɐ̃ʃsubʃtɐ̃sjɐˈsɐ̃w/. Vou focar só as duas primeiras sílabas, que são as que interessam: /tɾɐ̃ʃsɛ/, /tɾɐ̃ʃsi/ e /tɾɐ̃ʃsubʃ/ (/ʃ/ representa o som ***ch*** de ***ch***ato). Ou seja, o primeiro ***s*** de cada palavra daria origem ao som /ʃs/ como o ***sc*** de *con**sc**iência*. Esta é a pronúncia que eu esperaria do pessoal que chia o ***s***, como cariocas e portugueses. Da maior parte dos outros brasileiros, que não chiam o ***s***, esperaria /tɾɐ̃sɛ/, /tɾɐ̃si/ e  /tɾɐ̃subs/, já que para estes mesmo o ***sc*** de *consciência* se reduz a /s/, creio.

Ora estava eu a meditar sobre a curiosidade de um só ***s*** dar origem a dois sons, /ʃs/, quando fui consultar dicionários, e eis que aInfopédia diz que é [/tɾɐ̃sɛ/](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/transexual), [/tɾɐ̃si/](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/transiberiano) e [/tɾɐ̃subʃ/](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/transubstancia%C3%A7%C3%A3o). O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa confirma. Fui ver ao Forvo. Estas palavras são pouco comuns, mas há uma brasileira, uma carioca a julgar pelo mapa, que [pronuncia *transubstanciação*](http://pt.forvo.com/word/transubstancia%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt) com eu.

Ora a pergunta é então: sou só eu que pronuncio assim? Ou a minha pronúncia é generalizada aos s-chiantes, e a Infopédia e dicionário da Academia apresentam uma pronúncia teoricamente correta, mas descritivamente incorreta?

Se /tɾɐ̃ʃsɛ/, /tɾɐ̃ʃsi/ e /tɾɐ̃ʃsubʃ/ é pronúncia mais comum entre os que chiam o ***s***, como as reações até ao momento parecem indicar, qual a razão da presente grafia? Parece-me que a grafia mais adequada, como sugere o ANenes num comentário abaixo, seria *trans-siberiano*, etc. O Googe Books revela que a grafia com duplo ***s***, com ou sem hífen, também é ou foi usada. A grafia atual foi sempre a oficial?

Comment: Sim, parece-me que é com /ʃ/ que a maioria da gente em Portugal pronuncia (maioria em que me incluo). Exemplo: http://tviplayer.iol.pt/video/55c8f0ab0cf26f3adc011130

Comment: @Artefacto Não sei como é que me tinha esquecido de *transexual*.

Comment: ... nem sei que dizer. E já agora, porque não ler como em trânsito?? «Tran·zécs·u·al» e «tran·zi·be·ri·a·no»?

Comment: @ANeves Porque tu queres manter o som /s/ de _**s**exual, **s**iberiano_. Mas pelos vistos a maioria de nós mantém também o  /ʃ/  de _tran**s**_, mesmo que esse ***s*** se tenha perdido na escrita. Andei a ver, e já houve quem escrevesse *trans-siberiano* e *transsiberiano*.

Comment: Sim, exatamente. E da mesma maneira que quero manter o `/sɛ/` de «-sexual», quero manter o `/ɐ̃ʃ/` de «trans-». Antes de ler esta pergunta, acho que teria escrito *trans-siberiano*.

Comment: Eu pronuncio como "trans-si-be-ri-a-no"  com "s" na primeira e na segunda sílabas. E creio que essa é a pronuncia mais frequente por aqui.  O mesmo vale para "transexual" e "transubstanciação"

Comment: Em português brasileiro nesses casos não aparece o /ʃ/, nem nos sotaques em que o /s/ é comumente pronunciado como /ʃ/ em fim de palavra.

Comment: @Centaurus Do teu comentário anterior deduzi que pronuncias *transiberiano* como eu: /tɾɐ̃ʃsibəˈrjɐnu/ ou *tranch-siberiano*, mas o comentário do Enrico, imediatamente acima, deixa-me na dúvida. A única maneira que eu vejo de pronunciar dois ***s*** em *trans-si* é o primeiro ter o som *ch* de ***ch**ave* (/ʃ/).

Comment: @Jacinto  Sim, pronuncio "transiberiano" da mesma forma que tu pronuncias.   Já vi a palavra escrita algumas vezes mas não é uma palavra que se ouça por aqui.  Por esse motivo fica difícil dizer qual a pronuncia mais comum em pt-BR.  Já em "transexual", embora uma palavra mais comum, a presença ou ausência do "ch" pode ser sutil quando não há um motivo para focarmos nossa atenção nesse fonema e a palavra é pronunciada rapidamente.  Eu pronuncio "tranch-sexual" e acho que é a forma mais comum.  Eu disse acho.  Vou passar a prestar atenção nesse detalhe a partir de agora.

Comment: @Centaurus Obrigado pela clarificação. Isso que dizes é bem verdade, e nós raramente temos motivo para focar a atenção em fonemas individuais.

Comment: @Enrico Não estarás enganado? Vê o comentário do Centaurus acima.

Comment: @Jacinto Talvez o Enrico não seja carioca.  Nós aqui do Rio de Janeiro puxamos muito o "ch", influência da corte de Lisboa no Rio durante as guerras napoleônicas.  No restante do Brasil tendem ao "s" mais sibilante.

Comment: Sou de Minas Gerais.

Comment: @Enrico É muito fácil nós não nos apercebermos dos sons individuais. Por exemplo, eu só muito tarde me apercebi que eu, como todos os portugueses, pronuncio o ***s*** de *mesmo* como ***j***; tu provavelmente pronuncias como ***z***. Talvez estejas interessado sobre [este post](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan/1083#1083) dedicado à pronúncia do ***s*** em fim de sílaba.

Comment: @Enrico É claro que *transexual*, etc. é um caso diferente do ***s*** em fim de sílaba: aí eu e o Centaurus desdobramos o ***s*** em dois sons, como se a palavra se escrevesse *trans-sexual*.

Comment: @Jacinto Dou mta atenção à fonética e fonologia, principalmente pq era uma das minhas matérias favoritas na Linguística. Tô falando q falo assim pq falo assim, uai. =P

Comment: Alguém consegue pronunciar /ʃs/? Para mim é absolutamente impossível. Ou vira ʃ ou vira s, mas o encontro consonantal é impronunciável. Obs.: Sou gaúcho, moro em Brasília, mas passeia a infância e a adolescência no Rio de Janeiro. E lá, pelo que eu me lembre, o sc de adolescência era pronunciado /s/, nunca /ʃs/. Ou mudou, ou minha memória está equivocada, ou...

Comment: @Luís Todos os dias eu pronuncio /ʃs/ várias vezes antes do pequeno almoço. Não só em palavras como *transexual*, mas em todas as palavras com *sc* (desce, cresce, consciência; embora *piscina* seja frequentemente /pɨ'ʃinɐ/ ou mesmo  /'pʃinɐ/) e *xc* (*excitado, exceção*). O Centauro, carioca, pelos visto fala da mesma maneira.

Comment: De fato, ⟨sc⟩ é realizado como `/s/` no Brasil e como `/ʃs/` em Portugal. O dialeto carioca, nacionalmente conhecido por palatalizar o ⟨s⟩ (fenômeno que chamamos de "S chiado" ou "S carioca"), assemelha-se ao português europeu quanto à palatalização; mas ainda assim, possui o dígrafo `/ʃs/` somente em nomes decomponíveis. Ou seja, o "tran**s**iberiano" carioca (decomponível em "trans"+"siberiano") pode soar como o europeu, mas o "cre**sc**imento" não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente identifiquemos os componentes deste dígrafo:

- Coda sibilante: O ⟨s,z,x⟩ na posição de [coda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_(sil%C3%A1bica)) (i.e., no final de uma sílaba), que é realizado como os palatais `/ʃ,ʒ/` nos dialetos palatalizantes (Portugal e alguns dialetos brasileiros), ou como os alveolares `/s,z/` nos dialetos não-palatalizantes (maioria do Brasil).
- Ataque sibilante: O ⟨s, z, c/ç, x⟩ na posição de [ataque](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADlaba#Estrutura_interna), (i.e., no início de uma sílaba) que é realizado como os alveolares `/s,z/`.

O dígrafo formado por uma coda sibilante, no fim duma sílaba, seguido imediatamente por um ataque sibilante, na sílaba seguinte, é realizado de diferentes maneiras dependendo do dialeto.

Nos dialetos não-palatalizantes, onde tais codas são iguais aos ataques, nada acontece. Os fonemas se fundem num só: `/Vs.sV > VsV/` (onde `/V/` é uma vogal qualquer). Por exemplo, no Brasil, "con**sc**iência" é realizado como `/kõ.si'ẽ.si̯a̯/`.

Nos dialetos palatalizantes, onde as codas sibilantes são diferentes dos ataques, há duas possibilidades:

- Pronunciar apenas o ataque sibilante (`Vʃ.sV > VsV/`). Isso ocorre no português brasileiro.
- Pronunciar cada sibilante individualmente (`/Vʃ.sV > VʃsV/`). Isso ocorre no português europeu.

Tratemos do caso do português europeu. Quando, no dígrafo em questão, a coda sibilante da sílaba anterior é ⟨s, x⟩ e o ataque sibilante da sílaba seguinte é o ⟨c/ç⟩, tal como nas palavras ⟨con**sc**iência⟩, ⟨e**xc**elência⟩ ou ⟨tran**sc**edência⟩, a ortografia consegue transcrevê-los inequivocamente.

O problema ocorre quando o ataque sibilante é ⟨s-⟩. A ortografia falha em representar tais casos:

```
CASO.  CODA + ATAQUE > ORTOGRAFIAS POSSÍVEIS  EXEMPLO
  01. ⟨-ns⟩ + ⟨s-⟩   > "nss", "ns", "ns-s"    "transiberiano"
  02.  ⟨-s⟩ + ⟨s-⟩   > "ss", "s-s"            "pós-socialismo"
```

Palavras como ⟨transexual⟩ e ⟨transiberiano⟩ são escritas sobre uma falha ortográfica, incapaz escrever este dígrafo quando o ataque sibilante não é ⟨c⟩. Pois quando o ataque sibilante é ⟨c⟩, como em "tran**sc**edental", a ortografia representa o dígrafo inambiguamente.

Caso tua pronuncia de ⟨transexual⟩ com o dígrafo `/ʃs/` fosse a errada, também deveria ser ⟨transcíclico⟩. Pois ambas as palavras são composta pelos mesmos processos que descrevi: uma coda palatal seguida dum ataque alveolar. A pronúncia de ⟨transexual⟩ como `/tɾã(j)ʃ.se.ksu.al/` é também comum no Brasil em dialetos palatalizantes, como o carioca, principalmente pelo costume de pronunciar a forma reduzida desse nome (`/tɾã(j)ʃ/`) terminando em `/ʃ/`, daí a forma composta acaba tomando o fonema `/ʃ/` também.

Creio que o prefixo ⟨trans⟩ deveria ser escrito com um hífen (e.g., "trans-siberiano") tal como já faz-se com o prefixo ⟨pós⟩ (e.g., "pós-socialismo", realizado como `/ʃs/` no português europeu), o que evitaria esta ambiguidade.

O livro [The Phonology of Portuguese](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Onr9OFylajYC) descreve a variação da coda sibilante e o [artigo da Wikipedia anglófona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology) resume-a.

Comment: Já encontrei escrito com hífen. Em vários dicionários antigos vem com dois ss sem hífen: Morais Silva 1858, Domingos Vieira 1874. No Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913 vem *tansubstanciação* mas *transsecular;* no de 1939 já não vem nenhuma palavra com *transs-*. *Transubstanciação* tem de existir no latim; como se escreveria?

Comment: Em latino dobra-se a consoante: ["*tran**ss**exualis*"](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transsexualis), tal como no inglês ["*tran**ss**exual*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transsexual).

Comment: A palavra latina "*transsubstantiatio*" (transubstanciação, com ⟨s⟩ dobrado) é atestada num [documento do papa Pio XI](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xi/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_19280106_mortalium-animos.html) e [neste livro de Erasmus, de 1509](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/erasmus/moriae.shtml), basta dar CTRL-F e pesquisar pela palavra.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil estas palavras se pronunciam como se possuíssem dois esses (ss).

Isso provavelmente se deve ao fato de que a palavra sexual, siberiano e substanciação se pronunciam desta forma e a palavra trans é apenas um prefixo.

Comment: Isso significa que pronuncias como se fosse *tranciberiano?*

Comment: geralmente não. talvez se alguém pronunciar muito rápido, especialmente na região sul por conta do sotaque. geralmente o trans se pronuncia primeiro, quase como se fosse uma palavra separada e logo depois o sufixo. 
é como se houvesse um hífen trans-sexual.

Comment: por exemplo, existe uma rodovia no norte do país chamada transamazônica. nesse caso o s se pronuncia como se fosse um z da mesma forma que em trânsito. então creio que a regra é analisar o sufixo da palavra para conecer sua pronunciação.

Comment: Ah, ok, e como é que pronuncias o primeiro ***s?*** Porque há duas pronúncias no Brasil. Pronuncias como se fosse *trach-siberiano?*

Comment: aí depende,. no rio de janeiro e em regiões do pará o s é "chiado" então serian transch-siberiano. agora em outras partes como o nordeste seria algo como transciberiano (não é a pronuncia correta porém é a mais próxima que eu conseguiria descrever)

Answer (score 0):

A pronúncia predominante no Brasil, mesmo nos lugares onde o "s" pós-vocálico se pronuncia /ʃ/, é /tɾɐ̃s/, com talvez alguma variação para /tɾɐ̃is/. (E, no caso de "transexual", é /tɾɐ̃se/, com /e/ fechado, não /tɾɐ̃sɛ/, de novo com exceções regionais.)

Da mesma forma, "transatlântico" se pronucia /tɾɐ̃z/, e não /tɾɐ̃ʒz/.

/ʃs/ e /ʒz/ são muito difíceis de pronunciar para a maioria dos brasileiros.

Answer (score 0):

A maioria dos portugueses pronuncia como "transsexual" (trans-sexual), mas a forma correta "transexual" deverá ser pronunciada como "trã-sexual".

Fazendo a divisão silabica da palavra, temos então:

Na primeira silaba: **tr** é um *cluster* de consoantes inicial, pelo que constitui o ataque. Depois temos o **a** que fará parte do nucleo, por fim temos o **n** que fará parte da coda. O "s", sendo seguido de uma vogal, já fará parte da segunda silaba.

Portanto, na segunda silaba: **s** e **e** constituem respetivamente o ataque e o nucleo.

Terceira silaba: novamente temos uma consoante seguida de vogal: **x** e **u** que também constituem respeetivamente o ataque o nucleo.

Por fim, na quarta silaba, temos uma vogal, que fará parte do nucleo, e uma consoante final, que fará parte da coda.

Portanto concluimos que a divisão silabica é: **tran-se-xual**.

Agora a pronuncia: na primeira silaba temos um **a** seguido de um **n** na coda seguido, pelo que será um **a** nasal e o **n** é mudo.

Seguidamente, temos um s no ataque da segunda silaba, pelo que se lê **/s/** ou **/z/**, que neste caso é /s/ visto a palavra derivar de uma palavra iniciada por **s** que recebeu o sufixo **trans**.

Conclusão, a palavra **transexual**, grafada desta forma, lê-se **/tɾɐ̃.sɛ.ksu.ˈaɫ/**.

Comment: Qual é o teu critério para "forma correta" e "deverá"?

Comment: @Jacinto "forma correta" → "forma registada no dicionario"; "deverá" → "pelas regras ortograficas" (editei a resposta para clarificar este ultimo ponto).