# S não intervocálico que é pronunciado como se fosse

Tags: pronúncia

Por que o *s* é pronunciado como /z/ em *transar* e não como /s/, como em *tensão*, já que não é intervocálico?

Comment: Sempre tive essa dúvida.

Comment: Acho que isto se deve a que, em tempos, o Português tinha as sete, mas agora só tem quatro sons sibilantes. É possível que antes esta palavra fosse pronunciada com uma das sibilantes que já não pertencem à lingua. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilante O castelhano sofreu um processo semelhante, mas manteve 4 diferentes. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol

Comment: Eu faria a pergunta por um caminho inverso:  Por que na grafia de "transar" foi estabelecido o uso de "s" uma vez que a pronúncia é "z"  ?  Na língua portuguesa temos inúmeras palavras onde o "s" tem som de "z", isso não é nenhuma novidade.

Comment: Não sei a resposta, mas se fosse /s/, confundiria com "trançar".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Transar*** tem o ***s*** pronunciado /z/ porque deriva de *transação*, que também tem o ***s*** pronunciado /z/.

[***Transar*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/transar) vem de *transa* + *ar*; e [***transa*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/transa), também com ***s*** pronunciado /z/, é redução de *transação*.

Em palavras começadas por ***trans***, o ***s*** é pronunciado /z/ quando seguido de vogal, exceto se esse ***s*** vier originalmente do início da palavra seguinte. Por exemplo, o ***s*** de *trans* é pronunciado /z/ em:

> trânsito, transigir, transato, transatlântico.

Em palavras começadas por *trans* em que o ***s*** vem do início da palavra seguinte, como *transexual* e  *transiberiano*, parece que o ***s*** é pronunciado /s/ por quem não chia o ***s*** e /ʃs/ por quem chia, como em *na**sc**er*. Vê [esta pergunta sobre a pronúncia de *transexual*, etc.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/como-se-pronunciam-transexual-transiberiano-e-transubstancia%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Obrigado!  Assim, faz-se possível diferenciar trans + Ibéria de trans + Sibéria na pronúncia.  =)

Comment: @MarceloVentura É verdade. Mas não deixa de ser uma certa anomalia que duas palavras tão diferentes se escrevam da mesma maneira.

Answer (score 4):

A sequencia de letras ***ans*** tem som de /ɐ̃s/ em palavras como ***ganso*** e ***manso*** porque a pronúncia é inerente às raízes das palavras.

Mas em palavras formadas por composição de uma raíz com um sufixo ou desinéncia (e.g., *transar* e *transação*, todos da raíz *trans-*) a pronúncia é baseada na análise fonológica de cada componente em separado. Ou seja, em vez de pronunciar ***transar*** como uma única palavra (o que seria /trɐ̃.sar/, como em *trançar*), pronuncia-se analizando a pronúncia de cada morfema separadamente (o que a faz /trãz.ar/).

O mesmo ocorre no inglés, onde a sequencia de letras ***th*** da palavra *outhouse* é pronunciado /t.h/ com cada som separado, e não como o /ð/ de ***th***is, como é o esperado do dígrafo "th" intervocálico, pois baseia-se na pronúncia de dois morfemas concatenados (*out*+*house*).

Answer (score 0):

O s intervocálico tem som de z. Também o s tem som de z quando tem transação e seus derivados desde que haja vogal após o s e não haja s no início da palavra posterior.