# Por que às vezes o "s" tem som de "z" até entre vogal e consoante?

Tags: pronúncia, fonemas

Por exemplo, tem-se, *cansaço* onde o ***s*** representa o fonema /s/, e na palavra *transação* temos o ***s*** agora como um fonema /z/.

Existe alguma regra para isso? Quais os motivos para a ocorrência disso?

Comment: Já existe [esta pergunta acerca de palavras como *transação*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3257/s-n%C3%A3o-intervoc%C3%A1lico-que-%C3%A9-pronunciado-como-se-fosse/3258#3258). Creio que encontrarás lá a resposta à tua pergunta.