# Por que se escreve "ciência" e não, "sciência"?

Tags: etimologia, ortografia, escrita

Pelo que sei, a palavra "ciência" vem do latim "*scientia*", que era falado como "squiêntia". No inglês, se escreve "*science*", por causa da etimologia. Nambos, "sc" é falado como "s" e, "t" é escrito como "c" e falado como "s".

Então, por que, em português, se escreve "**c**iência" ao invés de "sciência", já que, em outras palavras, manteve "sc" pela etimologia? Por exemplo: "adole**sc**ente", "na**sc**er", "de**sc**er".

Comment: acho que não existe palavras em português iniciando com SC.

Comment: @Peixoto, também acho. Por que será?

Comment: acho q existe apenas alguns fonemas em portugues que são constituidos por duas consuantes e são utilizados em portugues. PR, LR, TR, BR. Acho q se pararmos para pensar, devem ser todos com a segunda letra em R.

Comment: @Peixoto LR? Não existe fonema LR... arranjas um exemplo de palavra com ele? (Em "palrar" não é: tem "pal" e "rar", o L r o R são de fonemas diferentes.)

Comment: tens razão...estou errado. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Até ao princípio do século XX escrevia-se *sciencia*. O s foi eliminado (e o acento circunflexo introduzido) com a [reforma ortográfica de 1911](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1911) em Portugal e o [Acordo Ortográfico de 1943](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1943) no Brasil. A eliminação do s foi parte da eliminação das consoantes mudas. Do mesmo modo, *assumpto* passou a *assunto*, *theatro* a *teatro*, etc.

No caso de *con**s**ciência, na**s**cer, de**s**cer*, o que se passa é que esses ss não são mudos em Portugal: essas palavras são pronunciadas como *con**ch**ciência, de**ch**cer, na**ch**cer*. Por exemplo, para um português *florecer* e *florescer* soam diferentes.

No caso brasileiro, o [Formulário Ortigráfico de 1943](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1943) diz o seguinte (IV Consoantes Mudas; negrito meu):

> Não se escrevem as consoantes que se não proferem: *asma, assinatura, ciência, sdiretor, ginásio, inibir, inovação, ofício, ótimo, salmo,* e não *asthma, assignatura, sciencia, director, gymnasio, inhibir, innovação, officio, optimo, psalmo.*
> Observação — **Escreve-se, porém, o s em palavras como *descer, florescer, nascer,* etc., e o x em vocábulos como exceto, excerto, etc., apesar de nem sempre se pronunciarem essas consoantes.**

O “nem sempre se pronunciarem essas consoantes” indica que por vezes se pronunciavam. Agora, o que eu não sei é se nessa altura quem pronunciava esses ss eram só os portugueses, e o formulário manteve o ss na escrita em atenção às necessidades de Portugal (o formulário brasileiro de 1943 resulta de um acordo entre Portugal e Brasil) ou se também no Brasil havia quem os pronunciasse.

Comment: Pronunciava-se ou pronuncia-se? Obrigado pela resposta. Coisa louca, por sinal.

Comment: Sabes o porquê de, no Brasil, se falar "sc" como "s"?

Comment: @Schilive, "Pronunciava-se ou pronuncia-se?"; imagino que isto se refira ao meu último parágrafo. Quero dizer, se por volta de 1943, quem pronunciava esses ss eram só o portugueses ou também alguns brasileiros; os portugueses continuam a pronunciá-los. Porque é que os brasileiros pronunciam sc como s? Bem, os que não chiam o s é fácil: para eles o s e o c em *nascer* teriam de qualquer modo o mesmo som, ç, portanto aquilo funde-se tudo num único ç, Os que chiam o s poderiam em princípio pronunciar como os portugueses (*nachcer*, etc.); >>

Comment: obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: >> Segundo várias respostas a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/como-se-pronunciam-transexual-transiberiano-e-transubstancia%c3%a7%c3%a3o) não o fazem. Porque não? eu não sei. Coisas da evolução da língua. Nota que parece já ter existido em Portugal a pronúncia *nacer* (de *nascer*). Rei D. Duarte (1391-1438) escrevia *nacer* e coisas assim (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/qual-%c3%a9-a-hist%c3%b3ria-da-pron%c3%bancia-chiada-e-n%c3%a3o-chiada-do-s-em-final-de-s%c3%adlaba)). Provavelmente coexistiram em Portugal >>

Comment: >> e foram para o Brasil uma variedade de pronúncias, e depois umas vingaram em Portugal, outras no Brasil.

Comment: Jacinto, quando os portugueses ainda não lhes chiavam os ss, provavelmente não falavam “nachcer”, pois esse “ch” viria do “s” atrás duma consoante, mas também não falavam assim como quando galego-português, que era “nastser”. Então, como será que falavam antes de chiarem os ss e depois de /ts/ > /s/, i.e., como Camões falava “? Se eu tivesse que chutar, diria que falavam como dois ss, isto é, “nas-ser” (dizendo s então outro s). Pergunto pois se tivessem transformado “nastser” em “nacer”, seria impossível saber se veio de “sts” ou não.

Comment: @Schilive, eu não sei quando é qualquer dessas alterações ocorreu. No português medieval, o s,ss (como em *sapo, passo*) representava um som diferente do ç, c(e,i): *sela* e *cela* não eram homófonos, mesmo depois de c já não ser /ts/. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%c3%a7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%c3%bancia-sinto-%e2%89%a0-cinto), onde até tens links para as duas pronúncias, que ainda persistem, ou persistiam ainda há pouco tempo, nalguns falantes do norte de Portugal.

Comment: Jacinto, talvez seja repetição do que já sabias, mas descobri recentemente que *nascer*, *descer*, *conhecer* e *esquecer* têm formas históricas *nacer*, *decer*, *conhoscer* e *escaescer* no século XIII, quando *ce* se falava /tse/, notando-se que todas essas palavras têm origem com "sc" ao invés de *c*. Então, provavelmente estavas certo que coexistiram, tendo algumas perdido o seu *s*, e outras mantido em Portugal. Eu talvez venha a pesquisar mais disso.

Comment: @Schilive, não sabia de todas essas palavras, mas sabia de algumas. Aliás já tinha mencionado isso num comentário acima (4 acima).

Comment: Jacinto, fiz esta listinha (mais dela no texto): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FUUCgAOX9kvFojggzNjQ3HUvK9eyDWgs/view?usp=sharing. Boa parte das palavras terminam em "-ecer", porque esse sufixo é bem usado, e inclui porque "-ecer" vem de "-escer".

Comment: @Schilive, muito curioso. E *nascer* e *descer* são até pouco frequentes e tardias!

Comment: Jacinto, em Os Lusíadas, há tanto *nascer* quanto *nacer*, entre outros. Em textos em galego-português, como na Demanda do Santo Graal e Cantigas de Santa Maria, também aparecem ambos. Então, ou falava-se *nacer* e havia confusão escrevendo, tentando seguir a etimologia, ou falavam-se ambos ou era para economizar papel ou era erro. Pelo esmero das obras, Camões e CSM, e tantos outros exemplos disso se fazendo, duvido ser erro. Os textos em galego-português eram escritos conforme a fala, então, provavelmente não era erro etimológico. Pelo que vejo, ou era economia de papel ou dupla pronúncia.>>

Comment: >> TODAVIA, nem as Cantigas de Santa Maria nem Camões (Camões li só um teco) faziam esse tipo de abreviatura, então, o mais provável é a dupla pronúncia. Só vou fazer outro comentário se eu tiver um livro ou um artigo, porque senão eu não consigo argumento melhor. Não é possível eu não encontrar nada!

Comment: @Schilive, já viste [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/qual-%c3%a9-a-hist%c3%b3ria-da-pron%c3%bancia-chiada-e-n%c3%a3o-chiada-do-s-em-final-de-s%c3%adlaba), precisamente sobre este assunto? Eu acho dupla pronúncia (se não tripla ou quádrupla) o mais provável: para se escrever *nacer* é porque deveria haver quem pronunciasse assim (não precisas de economizar papel em versos). Mas se não existisse também *nachcer, nastcer* ou coisas assim, não vejo como é que *nachcer* apareceria depois (acho improvável influência de escrita etimológica numa palavra tão comum).

Answer (score 0):

Muito dessas palavras que mudaram, altera a pronúncia "sciência" era falado "chiência" a palavra "director" muda também, era mudo mas o "c" servia para aumentar a vogal, sem o "c" fica "dirêtor" em vez de "dirétor"

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, Grilo!. Em português do Brasil, é “dirêtôr” oxítona. Isso seria o mesmo para “recepção” e “aspecto”? Segundamente, neste site, Grilo, tenta-se usar referências nas resposta, pois uma resposta sem referências é basicamente equivalente ao argumento “o mundo gira porque eu quero”.