# Em que regiões do Brasil se chia o «s»?

Tags: pronúncia, português-brasileiro

É sabido que os portugueses e os cariocas chiam o ***s***. Isto é, o ***s*** em fim de sílaba é pronunciado /ʃ/ ― como o ***ch*** de ***ch**ato* ― se for seguido por consonante surda ― /k/, /f/, /p/, etc. ― ou, no fim de palavra, por pausa longa; e é pronunciado /Ʒ/ ― como ***j*** de ***j**arro* ― se for seguido de consoante sonora ― /b/, /d/, /g/, etc. Ver esta [pergunta sobre a pronúncia do ***s*** em fim de sílaba](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan/1083#1083) e esta sobre [consoantes sonoras e surdas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade).

Mas parece-me que se chia o ***s*** também noutras regiões do Brasil. O [Forvo.com](http://pt.forvo.com/) tem palavras pronunciadas por várias pessoas. O site mostra a localização dos falantes no mapa, eu encontrei exemplos de chiamento do ***s*** fora do Rio de Janeiro. Mostro alguns exemplos (indico apenas a pronúncia do  ***s*** e escrevo o resto da palavra normalmente):

> [***MeƷmo***](http://pt.forvo.com/word/mesmo/#pt) no litoral do estado de São Paulo, mas *me**z**mo* em Santa Catarina, e não sei bem como no Pernambuco.
>
> [***Eʃtar deitado***](http://pt.forvo.com/word/estar_deitado/#pt) e  [***Eʃtar sentado***](http://pt.forvo.com/word/estar_sentado/#pt) em Paraíba.
>
> [***Eʃtudar***](http://forvo.com/word/estudar/#pt) no Rio Grande do Sul (pela veraluz16) e em Tocatins?

Alguém sabe então onde se chia o ***s*** no Brasil, ou há algum estudo sobre o assunto?

Comment: É uma pergunta que eu deveria saber responder, mas não sei.   Sei apenas que no Rio de Janeiro o "s" é chiado.  Em São Paulo, Minas Gerais e no Espírito Santo não é.  Desconheço algum outro local do Brasil onde o "s" seja pronunciado da  mesma forma que no Rio de Janeiro. Sempre tive a impressão, mas não tenho a certeza, que os estados do sul (Paraná, Santa Catarina e RS) seguem o modelo paulista.

Comment: Talvez no Litoral norte junto a divisa de estados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O *s* chiado é uma herança dos portugueses, mas não foi adotado em todas as regiões do Brasil. Uma justificativa pode ser a miscelânea de imigrantes que se estabelece em algumas regiões, formando, através da interação cultural, novas maneiras de falar. Um bom exemplo é o Rio Grande do Sul, colonizado, em grande parte, por portugueses, espanhóis, italianos e alemães.

É comum ouvir o *s* desta maneira na região Nordeste, no Rio de Janeiro e em Santa Catarina, especialmente na Grande Florianópolis (região da capital de Santa Catarina) e em algumas cidades do Vale do Itajaí (região ao norte da Grande Florianópolis). Isto é algo bastante curioso. Em Brusque e Itajaí (cidades do Vale do Itajaí) é comum chiar o *s*, enquanto Blumenau e Pomerode (também cidades do Vale, mas com influência alemã), embora próximas, não.

Nos estados seguintes não é comum chiar o *s*: Rio Grande do Sul, Paraná, São Paulo, Espírito Santo, Minas Gerais, Mato Grosso, Mato Grosso do Sul e Goiás.

Aproveitando: sou natural do Rio Grande do Sul e não conheço pessoas nascidas lá que falem /eʃtudar/.

Comment: Imagino que grande parte da tua resposta se baseie em conhecimento pessoal direto (por exemplo, os pormenores que dás do estado de Santa Catarina). Ou isto é tudo do conhecimento geral no Brasil, algum estudo a que tiveste acesso?

Comment: Infelizmente, não possuo estudos sobre o assunto. Se tiver acesso a algum, posto aqui para complementar a resposta, @Jacinto.

Comment: Que a pronúncia chiada seja herança dos portugueses, e a não chiada seja influência doutros povos é que me parece menos claro. A pronúncia não chiada parece já ter existido em Portugal, e pode até ter sido a original. Vê [esta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/qual-%C3%A9-a-hist%C3%B3ria-da-pron%C3%BAncia-chiada-e-n%C3%A3o-chiada-do-s-em-final-de-s%C3%ADlaba).

Answer (score 3):

O /s/ também chia em Recife, mas como a entoação das palavras e frases tem um "cantado" diferente, as pessoas de outra região prestam mais atenção ao cantado do que ao chiado do /s/ recifense. Se puder ouvir a torcida do Sport Recife gritando é fácil perceber, eles gritam "iXxpóó", "iXxxpóó" em vez de "iSsport". Em João Pessoa também chia, mas apenas os /s/ que estão no meio da palavras, por exemplo, "besteiras" soa como "beXteiraSs".

Answer (score 3):

Não tenho uma lista completa, mas o 's' é chiado especialmente em regiões que receberam um influxo de imigrantes portugueses que:

- era considerável, comparado ao tamanho da população local; e
- ocorreu num momento posterior ao início da colonização.

A primeira condição aumenta as chances do modo de falar dos imigrantes se tornar dominante. A segunda, por vezes associada a um certo grau de isolamento geográfico, aumenta as chances da forma particular de falar ter se preservado até os dias de hoje frente à pronúncia dominante no país.

O exemplo mais famoso, o Rio de Janeiro, recebeu a corte portuguesa no início do século XIX e, se o número de imigrantes não era tão grande comparado à população local, seu status tornava sua influência desproporcionalmente grande.

Outros dois exemplos importantes são Belém do Pará e Florianópolis. Como explica [essa matéria](https://super.abril.com.br/cultura/sotaques-do-brasil/) da revista SuperInteressante:

> Colonizadas depois do Nordeste e do Sudeste do País, as regiões Norte e Sul receberam, a partir do século 17, imigrantes da Ilha dos Açores e da Ilha da Madeira, onde é comum que o S assuma o som de SH. Em 1929, 15,6 mil portugueses viviam no Pará, a quarta maior população portuguesa do Brasil à época. [...] Outras cidades, entretanto, também receberam levas de açorianos e madeirenses sem que eles impusessem o S chiado – Porto Alegre foi uma delas. Elisa Battisti, do Instituto de Letras da UFRGS, explica que a posição geográfica e o tamanho da população de Florianópolis e Belém foram propícios para perpetuar a forma de falar dosh portuguesesh ilhéush. “Quando os açorianos chegaram a Florianópolis, o número de habitantes era pequeno, e houve um isolamento geográfico importante até o século 20.

Mas essa explicação não parece cobrir todos o casos. No nordeste brasileiro, por exemplo, em estados como Ceará, Alagoas e Pernambuco, versões do 's' chiado também são encontradas [1] e mesmo o Pará não era tão pouco populado quando da nova onda de imigração portuguesa no início do século XX (como apontou Jacinto nos comentários).

[1]  Dissertação de mestrado "A VARIAÇÃO FONÉTICA DO  EM TEMPO REAL EM DUAS LOCALIDADES SERGIPANAS - PROPRIÁ E ESTÂNCIA", Cláudia Santos de Jesus, UFBA, pg. 85 em diante ([e-print](https://alib.ufba.br/sites/alib.ufba.br/files/jesus_claudia_santos_de_dissertacao_letras_2014.pdf)).

Comment: Obrigado por isto. Já tinha visto essa hipótese de o s chiado ter sido levado pela imigração portuguesa, mas mantenho uma certa reserva. Afinal a língua portuguesa foi levada pela imigração portuguesa, possivelmente o s não chiado também foi. Não vi ainda ninguém mostrar que o s chiado surgiu em Portugal só depois da colonização inicial do Brasil, ou que tenha havido um tempo em que o português do Brasil não tivesse o s chiado e Portugal tivesse. Esses 15.600 portugueses no Pará em 1929, se estivessem todos em Belém, não chegariam a 10% da população da cidade.

Comment: @Jacinto Sobre Belém, não consegui achar, numa busca rápida, o porquê da influência possivelmente desproporcional desses portugueses sobre a pronúncia local, pode ter sido um acidente histórico. Sobre o pt-PT sem chiado, a dissertação que agora cito menciona (pg. 85): "Jerônimo  Soares  Barbosa  (1822,  p.  52),  no  capítulo  intitulado  “Dos  vícios  da pronunciação”, observa que os brasileiros “pronuncião com Z o  S  liquido, [...] dizendo: Mizterio, Fazto, Livros novoz, em  vez  de Mistério, Fasto, Livros  novos”, indicando uma diferença em relação a Portugal".

Comment: Pois, é possível que tenhas de pôr muito acidente histórico nisso. Esse Barbosa fez um levantamento do pronúncia no Brasil todo? Era uma país muito grande já nessa altura. É claro que isto está à margem da pergunta. Será mais fácil determinar uma mapa da pronúncia atual, que saber quando e como se formou. [O s/ss (mas não o c(i/e)/ç) em princípio de sílaba soava originalmente intermédio entre ç e ch](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%c3%a7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%c3%bancia-sinto-%e2%89%a0-cinto) >>

Comment: >> A minha conjetura é que no fim de sílaba também (não vejo por que é que deveria ser diferente), e que a certa altura esse som pendeu para ch nuns falantes e para ç noutros, dando origem aos ss chiado e não chiado. Se isto foi posterior à colonização inicial. o s chiado poderia aparecer no Brasil tal como em Portugal; se foi anterior, na vaga inicial de colonos iriam em princípio as duas pronúncias, e poderia em certas regiões prevalecer o s chiado desde o início.

Comment: @Jacinto Concordo contigo. Sobre o Barbosa e se ele "fez um levantamento do pronúncia no Brasil todo?", o texto da própria tese que o cita lamenta que ele não especifique a que região se referia.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui no Ceará chiamos o S sempre no meio das palavras. como em “festa” falamos “feshta” mas no plural “festas” não pronunciamos “feshtash” e sim “feshtas”. Dependendo do bairro de Fortaleza, e da condição socioeconômica, não se chia o S nunca, falando de uma forma mais parecida com o sotaque de São Paulo. Fortaleza tem sotaques diferentes de acordo com a região da cidade, e o interior do Ceará tem o mesmo sotaque do interior da Paraíba e Pernambuco. Fortaleza é distante de outras capitais e sofre muita influência de São Paulo. Aqui também tem uma comunidade numerosa e ativa de imigrantes portugueses recentes, especialmente nos bairros mais nobres, porém eles não tiveram muita influência na cultura da cidade.

Comment: Portanto, "Aqui no Ceará chiamos o S...", queres dizer "Aqui no Ceará **exceto em certos bairros de Fortaleza**..:"?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente as regiões litorâneas a partir do Rio de Janeiro para cima. Esse chiado é devido ao grande fluxo de portugueses nessas áreas. Com o povoamento do interior das regiões Nordeste e Norte, o S chiado foi sendo carregado e é encontrado nessas regiões mais interioranas também.

Já as regiões do centro e indo ao sul (de Goiás para baixo), houve um levante de povos de todos os lados (japoneses, italianos, alemães, ingleses, etc.). Por essa razão, o S não sofreu predominantemente a influência portuguesa litorânea.

Comment: Discordo completamente.  Em todo o litoral do estado do Espírito Santo o "s" não é chiado.  Também nos estados do sul, notadamente Santa Catarina e Rio Grande do Sul, o fluxo considerável de imigrantes portugueses foi grande e não pronunciam o "s" chiado como os cariocas.

Comment: E acrescento ainda que o "s chiado" é típico dos cariocas (aqueles que nasceram e habitam a cidade do Rio de Janeiro) mas não de todos os fluminenses (aqueles que nasceram e habitam todo o estado do Rio de Janeiro)

Comment: A adoção da pronúncia da corte pelos habitantes da cidade do Rio de Janeiro deveu-se **provavelmente** (opinião pessoal) ao fato de que aqui chegaram, em 1808, cerca de 15.000 nobres portugueses quando a população da cidade não passava de 50.000 indivíduos.  Desses, a maioria pertencia às camadas menos favorecidas.  A elite local provavelmente tratou logo de adotar o "sotaque de Lisboa" e a camada mais baixa, por imitação, também o fez.

Comment: Note o "basicamente" no início da postagem. Não falei hora nenhuma que era TODO O LITORAL.

Comment: Em apoio a essa resposta, posso relatar que é costumeiro "chiar" o _s_ em Santos, cidade portuária de São Paulo, estado onde, via de regra, não se "chia" o _s_.