# Qual é a história da pronúncia chiada e não chiada do «s» em final de sílaba?

Tags: pronúncia, origem, fonologia

Atualmente a o ***s*** em fim de sílaba é pronunciado como ***ç*** de *ra**ç**ão* ou ***z*** de *ra**z**ão*  pela maioria dos brasileiros (***s*** não chiado); e como ***ch*** de ***ch**ato* ou  ***j*** de ***j**ato*) por portugueses, cariocas e alguns outros brasileiros (***s*** chiado). [Esta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan/1083#1083) explica quando é que é ***ç*** ou ***ch*** (antes de consoante surda ou pausa) e quando é que é ***z*** ou ***j*** (antes de consoante sonora ou vogal). E [as respostas a esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/em-que-regi%C3%B5es-do-brasil-se-chia-o-s) dão-nos uma ideia das regiões do Brasil onde se chia o ***s***.

A minha questão é **qual é a origem destas duas pronúncias: quando é que surgiram e se propagaram?** E se alguém conseguir explicar como surgiram, tanto melhor. Consigo pensar pelo menos em três possibilidades:

1. As duas pronúncias vêm já da pré-história do português, e o ***s*** não chiado extinguiu-se em Portugal depois de passar ao Brasil.
2. O ***s*** chiado é o original no português, e o ***s*** não chiado surgiu e expandiu-se no Brasil.
3. O ***s*** não chiado é o original no português, e mais tarde o ***s*** chiado surgiu e substituiu o não chiado em Portugal e partes do Brasil.

Posso adiantar já que a (2) me parece improvável, porque já no século XV há textos que sugerem a existência do ***s*** não chiado em Portugal. Encontramos frquentemente *nacer* em vez de *nascer* e *conciência* em vez de *consciencia*. Isto sugere que o ***s*** era nesta palavras não chiado e o ***sc*** era pronunciado como um único ***ç***. E encontramos *nescessidade*, *nescessario*, etc. em vez de *necessidade* e *necessario*, o que sugere que o escritor sabia da existência de ***ss*** mudos e hipercorrigia. Deixo aqui exemplos do [*Livro da Montaria* de D. João I, 1357-1433](https://archive.org/stream/livrodamontariaf00johnuoft/livrodamontariaf00johnuoft_djvu.txt) (ênfase minha):

> Ora devedes a saber que dos cadelinhos a ***nacença*** que milhor he assi he na entrada do inverno. E portanto todollos monteiros non devem a lançar as cadelas aos caães senon no tempo do estio, e esto por lhe ***naçerem*** os cadelinhos na entrada do inverno.
> [...]
> Assi, quando os monteiros quiserem escolher os cadelinhos non os devem a escolher senon do dia que ***nascerem*** a dez dias atá quinze

Por outro lado, se a hipótese (3) for correta, põe-se a questão de como é que o ***s*** se manteve na escrita em palavras como *nascer*. Haveria na pronúncia do português antigo uma distinção entre consoantes duplas e únicas, como acontece hoje no italiano?

Comment: Boa pergunta! Em teoria há mais uma possibilidade: o ***s*** chiado podia ter nascido em Portugal e depois desaparecido no Brasil. Me parece que o Wikipédia no inglês [está a concordar com a sua opção (3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Portuguese#Medieval_sound_changes), mas parece não citar nenhuma fonte.

Comment: @DanGetz Há muitas mais possibilidades. Eu identifiquei "pelo menos três", que me parecem as mais básicas. A tua sugestão parece-me uma variante das minhas (2) ou (1), não?

Comment: sim, é verdade.

Comment: Jacinto o povo facilmente inventa sonoridades novas e descobrir como aparecem não é simples. Imagina que estávamos em 1900 e Braga era a capital de Portugal, a esta altura toda a gente dizia «b» e «v» da mesmo forma...

Comment: Sou brasileira e fiz mestrado em ciências da linguagem em Portugal. Uma colega do mestrado comentou que sua mãe (que era de Trás-os-montes, se não me engano) pronunciava de formas diferentes os ss, sc, c e ç, e usava essa sua pronúncia para ensinar a grafia correta das palavras à filha. A colega não conseguiu repetir as pronúncias, e fiquei muito curiosa para saber como eram. Qualquer dia pergunto-lhe.

Comment: Olá Tamires, bem-vinda ao site. Já há [esta pergunta sobre essas duas pronúncias](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%C3%A7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%C3%BAncia-sinto-%E2%89%A0-cinto); poderás querer ver. Essa outra pronúncia do *ss* em Trás-os-Montes (um pouco ente *ç* e *ch*; *sinto* fica algo entre *cinto* e *chinto*, ao passo que *cinto* é mesmo *cinto*) poderá ter sido a original que deu origem ao s chiado e não chiado em fim de sílaba. Mas este teu comentário é, bem um comentário e não uma resposta; e este espaço é para respostas.

Comment: (O comentário anterior do Jacinto parece estranho, porque estava debaixo de uma resposta da Tamires que foi convertida para um comentário aqui. Ao converter, deixei o comentário do Jacinto vir também; porque tem ligações interessantes.)

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que a pronúncia [s] (**s** não chiado) é a original no latim. Provavelmente, ela chegou ao Brasil sem mudanças e, depois, passou a ser [ʃ] (**s** chiado) em Portugal e no Rio de Janeiro (talvez pela influência lusitana durante o período em que foi capital do Brasil). Essa mudança, contudo, não afetou dialetos periféricos ou mais conservativos.

Quanto à existência do dígrafo *sc*, provavelmente vem de formas resgatadas da escrita latina, mas já com pronúncia alterada. *Nascer* originou-se do latim *nascĕre*, palavra pronunciada de forma semelhante a "nas-ke-re" (**s** não chiado). *Fascículo* vem do latim *fascicŭlus*, pronunciado de forma semelhante a "fas-ki-ku-lus".

O mesmo ocorreu com *anel*, cuja origem é o termo latino *annellus*. *N* intervocálico desapareceu, com certa frequência, na passagem do latim para o português, fenômeno que fez *annellus* tornar-se *elo* na língua portuguesa. Entretanto, com o resgate de grafias semelhantes às latinas, o uso de *anel* tornou-se mais comum.

Comment: Está bem observado que se a pronúncia desses *ss* era não chiada no latim, que essa pronúncia se mantivesse no português. Já o *sc* ser resgatado mais tarde me parece menos plausível. Não é só uma questão de grafia; é pronúncia também: os portugueses, e imagino que todos os que chiam o ***s***, pronunciam /ʃs/ o *sc* de *nascer, crescer, consciência*, etc. Se o *sc* dessas palavras passasse a certa altura a ser pronunciado como um só /s/, não estou a ver como é que o [ʃ] apareceria mais tarde nessas palavras. Se fossem palavras eruditas, tudo vem; (continua)

Comment: Mas essas palavras são tão comuns, que não estou a ver a pronúncia delas vir a ser influenciada pela grafia erudita. Portanto estou mais inclinado a pensar que houve sempre gente em Portugal que de algum modo identificava dois sons nesses *sc*; isto é, que *(ele) desce* e *(se ele) desse* não eram homófonos, como imagino que são atualmente na pronúncia com *s* chiado.

Comment: Tenho uma grande curiosidade: quem começou a chiar primeiro e o que influenciou esse chiado?

Answer (score 2):

Nenhuma das pronúncias é a original. Acredita-se que no século XVI todas as sibilantes do português, não apenas aquelas em final de sílaba, fossem realizadas ou como uma sibilante apico-alveolar surda /s̺/ ou como modal/obstruente /z̺/, que ainda são típicas do espanhol europeu, do galego e dos dialetos setentrionais do português europeu. Para os falantes de línguas em que não figura nenhuma destas, soam como algo intermédio entre [ʃ] e [s]. Em Portugal, as sibilantes apico-alveolares evoluíram o conhecido chiado enquanto que no Brasil deram origem a uma fricativa alveolar surda.

Comment: Henrique, as minhas desculpas por só agora ver a tua resposta, que me parece muito interessante. O que eu gostaria era de mais pormenores/referências. Umas qualificações. Quando dizes "Em Portugal, as sibilantes apicoalveolares evoluíram o conhecido chiado", tás a falar só em fim de sílaba, certo? (Nós dizemos [s]im, não [ʃ]im.) E "todas as sibilantes do português [....] realizadas ou como sibilante apicoalveolar [...] ou modal/obstruente /z̺/" tas a falar das habitualmente representados pela letra s, certo? Porque havia outras sibilantes, só que não representadas por s.

Answer (score 0):

A influência árabe no portugues em Portugal, na época se via no vestir, na música, e no idioma.
O S Chiado é influência de uma variação do árabe.
Confira o vídeo no YouTube: https://youtu.be/0uraXoqkzEE
Como a maior parte dos árabes se concentraram no Sul e centro de Portugal, no Norte, onde a língua portuguesa nasceu, a pronúncia do S é menos frequente,  por ser mais próxima do galego, e por influência inglesa desde o século XII para XIII
Confira no vídeo do YouTube: https://youtu.be/zvStEeNzM2Q

Answer (score -2):

O S chiado não se deve considerar como português mas, sim, como lisboeta (ou alfacinha), quer dizer, relativo à região da capital de Portugal. Fora de Lisboa continua a usar-se o S não chiado.
Também em Lisboa, as consoantes SC têm som de CH, assim, descer pronuncia-se "dexer (decher)", mas noutras regiões a pronúncia é "des-cer", com destaque do S e do C.

Comment: Deves estar a fazer uma confusão qualquer. Eu não sou lisboeta, e em todo o lado por onde andei em Portugal sempre ouvi o ***s*** chiado em fim de sílaba. O JorgeB e o ANeves são do norte e dizem a mesma coisa nas respostas a [esta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan/1083#1083). *Descer* é um bom exemplo. Quem não chia o ***s*** pronuncia come se fosse *decer*; quem chia, pronuncia como *dech.cer*. Ouve [aqui](https://pt.forvo.com/word/descer/#pt) as duas pronúncias.