# Sobre som que <sc> representa

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia, português-europeu, fonologia

As palavras "nascer", "crescer", "descer", etc vêm do galego-português "nacer", "crecer", "decer" etc e eram, como se pode deduzir, faladas com a africada /t͡s/, que no português passou a ser /s/ e assim foi passada para o Brasil.

Teria a pronúncia portuguesa de tais palavras (com /-ʃ.ˈs-/) sido causada por uma relatinização tardia de tais palavras? Se não o for, como pode ter acontecido tal mudança?

Comment: @Schilive Creio que *nascer* será /nɐʃˈseɾ/ no Portugal e /nɐʃˈθeɾ/ na Galiza, mas não tenho boas referências em este momento.

Comment: @tchrist, bom lembrarmo-nos que faz mais de 500 anos desde que o galego e o português se separaram, e que houve influência do espanhol em galego. Antes de tirarmos conclusões, teríamos que ver isso melhor. Um problemão de vê-lo melhor é a falta de coisas escritas em galego. Sem falar que o português brasileiro não chia majoritariamente seus as. Ou seja, é complicado, mas interessantíssimo. Obrigado.

Comment: @Schilive , sabe dizer em qual texto de Teyssier especificamente?

Comment: Ergative Man, sim. Livro “história da língua portuguesa” por Paul Teyssier, traduzido por Celso Cunha.

Comment: [Talvez tenha algo a ver com isso?](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_das_sibilantes_do_castelhano#Descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o_fon%C3%A9tica) Acho que mencionam o português um pouco lá.

Comment: @Schilive, revê lá o teu Teysser. A *Gramática do Português* diz que o /t͡s/ (como em paço) deu em /s/ alveolar pré-dorsal (imagino que mais ou menos o mesmo que pré-dorsodental); o s de *passo* é que era já do latim /s/ apicoalveolar; vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4580/dialetos-que-conservam-diferen%c3%a7as-de-sibilantes-na-pron%c3%bancia-sinto-%e2%89%a0-cinto). Com /t͡s/ → /s/ aveolar pré-dorsal, em *na**sc**er* ficariam duas consoantes parecedíssimas juntas (apicoalveolar seguida de alveolar pré-dorsal). Pergunto-me se o chiamento não >>

Comment: >> começaria nalgumas zonas antes da passagem  /t͡s/ → /s/ aveolar pré-dorsal, evitando assim a assimilação de um /s/ pelo outro. Se foi isto começaríamos a ter uma resposta para [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/qual-%c3%a9-a-hist%c3%b3ria-da-pron%c3%bancia-chiada-e-n%c3%a3o-chiada-do-s-em-final-de-s%c3%adlaba?noredirect=1&lq=1) relacionada, e encalhada há anos. Ou talvez eu esteja a subestimar a agilidade da língua e fineza do ouvido, e nós sejamos perfeitamente capazes, se treinados de pequeninos, de produzir e ouvir o apicoalveolar seguido do pré-dorsal.

Comment: Em glossa.gal, todas as palavras com "sce" ou "sci" podem ser "ce" ou "ci", logo me parece que havia duas possibilidades de pronúncia, i.e., havia "nascer" e "nacer". Os /ts/ haviam se transformado em /s/ pré-dorsodentais, início do século 1500, mantendo a distinção entre "acender" e "ascender", mas em 1550, vê-se que há falantes confundindo os dois; em 1600, essa distinção morre — com excessão do norte português —, /s/ pré-dorsodentais se tornam /s/ ápico-alveolares. Quando e como esse chiamento aconteceu? De acordo com Teyssier, não temos certeza. Porém, as coisas PODEM ter mudado.

Comment: @Schilive, o pessoal a trocar os passos pelos paços (o apicoalveolar passar a alveolar pré-dorsal, o som do ç, ss atuais), diz a Gramática do Português que já acontecia no século XIII em Lisboa e no Algarve (vê a primeira das perguntas que eu linkei).

Comment: @Schilive, essa é uma hipótese que eu menciono nos meus primeiros dois comentários. Sistematizando. Símbolos: *a**ss**o* /s̺/; *a**ç**o* /t͡s/ → /š/; *a**ch**o* /ʃ/. Então, a tua sugestão é, para *na**sc**er* /nɐ**s̺t͡s**eɾ/ → /nɐ**s̺š**eɾ/ → /nɐ**ʃš**eɾ/. É possível. Mas como já disse acima, /s̺/ e /š/ são muito parecidos, e pergunto-me se um deles não reria rapidamente assimilado pelo outro (foi talvez isso que aconteceu na pronúncia não chiada: /nɐ**s̺t͡s**eɾ/ → /nɐ**s̺š**eɾ/ → /nɐ**š**eɾ/). >>

Comment: >> A outra hipótese que eu adiantei acima é /nɐ**s̺t͡s**eɾ/ → nɐ**ʃt͡s**eɾ/ → /nɐ**ʃš**eɾ/; ou seja o chiamento apareceria primeiro; como /ʃ/ e /š/ são mais diferentes (do que /s̺/ e /š/) , não haveria tanta pressão para assimilação. Há falantes no norte de Portugal que preservam a distinção entre /s̺/ e /š/ (pelo menos ainda havia no final do sXX; felizes, porque sabem sempre se se escreve *cegar* ou *segar*; já eu por vezes me engano!), mas não, que eu saiba, com os dois sons contíguos. Mas respondendo ao Ergative, **não** creio mesmo nada que tenha sido /nɐ**š**eɾ/)  → /nɐ**ʃš**eɾ/. >>

Comment: >> Até porque, uma coisa é relatinação de palavras mais cultas como *opoente → oponente* ou *sutil*  → (em Portugal) *subtil*. Mas com palavras populares como *nascer, descer, crescer* ??

Comment: Interessante que hoje falamos “padecer”, mas lat. *“patescere” > port. arc. “padescer” > port. hodierno “padecer”. Então nem todas as palavras que se falavam “stse” (“sce”) ou “stsi” (“sci”) são faladas como “chse” ou “chsi”.

Comment: Procurei várias coisas, mas sem conclusão certa. **1.** Vendo no Wikcionário os descendentes naturais de *nasco*, *cresco*, *descendo*, *-sco* (incoativo), *misceo*, *piscem*, *fascem*: talvez português seja a *única* língua *ibérica* que preserva o som SÇ /s̺s/ (hoje /ʃs/), que tipicamente se torna Ç /s/ (-ecer; esp. mecer, pez /s→θ/) ou X /ʃ/ (mexer, peixe, feixe; cat. néixer, créixer, aparèixer; arag. naxer, crexer confiando no Wikcionário); logo comparar com os vizinhos é difícil. **2.** Uns poucos escritores medievais usavam SÇ, mas talvez fosse só por amor ao latim. (continua...)

Comment: (…continuando) **3.** Uma *relatinização talvez* repusesse o som SÇ, mesmo em *palavras populares*, assim como chor→flor, fruito→fruto, auto→ato. **4.** -ecer é justificável nambos casos: se SÇ era pronunciado, a simplificação SÇ→Ç aconteceria talvez em palavras mais longas ou com outra condição; se SÇ não era assim pronunciado, talvez não ajustaram -ecer porque muitas dessas palavras eram incomuns ou inexistentes no latim clássico (p.ex., esquecer e parecer de \**excadescere* e \**parescere*, nunca escritos; já *apparescere* aparece poucas vezes). Portanto, **nenhuma conclusão**.

Answer (score -1):

Schilive escreveu em um comentário:

> Em glossa.gal, todas as palavras com "sce" ou "sci" podem ser "ce" ou "ci", então, me parece que havia duas possibilidades de pronúncia, i.e., havia "nascer" e "nacer". Os /ts/ haviam se transformado em /s/ ápico-alveolares, início do século 1500,  mantendo a distinção entre "acender" e "ascender", mas em 1550, vê-se que já há falantes confundindo os dois; em 1600, essa distinção morre, /s/ ápico-alveolares se tornam /s/ pré-dorsodentais. Quando e como esse chiamento aconteceu? De acordo com Teyssier, não se tem certeza, não sabemos.