# Tabela dos fonemas com exemplos de sonoridade

Tags: fonemas

## Problema

Por vezes encontro referências aos diversos fonemas, que não compreendo por não os conhecer. Por exemplo:

> - Do all Portuguese — from the Algarve to Bragança — pronounce a [**palatized sibilant** “s”](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan) at the end of a syllable?
> - [(...)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/do-all-portuguese-from-the-algarve-to-bragan%C3%A7a-pronounce-a-palatized-sibilan/1067#comment2726_1066) que inclui as posições alveolar simples, alveolar apical retraído ("alveolar retroflexo"), alveolar laminal palatalizado, palato-alveolar laminal e (...)

Então tenho de pesquisar cada um deles isoladamente para tentar perceber o que são, e principalmente procurar exemplos.

## Questão

Existe alguma fonte que apresente os diversos tipos de fonemas?
Sibilante não-africado, alveolar simples, pós-alveolar, etc.?

Procuro uma fonte com exemplos auditivos ou IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet).

---

Answers in English are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esta [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) Chart with sounds](https://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm) parece ser bem completa. Tem os símbolos, o som correspondente, e os nomes em inglês, bi-labial plosive, alveolar fricative, e coisas assim.

Mas para uma consulta rápida ficam aqui as tabelas de monotongos (vogais, exceto ditongos e tritongos) e consoantes que eu adaptei do artigo da [Wikipédia sobre Fonologia da língua portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) (obrigado, tchrist).

### Monotongos

> [image]
> Adaptado de [Fonologia da Língua Portuguesa (Wikipédia).](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa)

Estas tabelas são mais simples que [IPA Chart with sounds](https://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm) porque contêm apenas os sons relevantes para a língua portuguesa. Incluí nas tabelas exemplos para ilustrar apenas os sons representado pelos símbolos que poderiam suscitar confusão. Nas vogais, o [i] e o [u] e os símbolos com til representam os sons habituais dessas letras no português. Há ainda em São Paulo o [ɪ] (próximo do [i]) e [ʊ] (próximo do [u]), que eu não sei em que palavras ocorrem. A tabela indica também para Lisboa um [ɯ] muito parecido com [ɨ], mas é uma diferença que eu nunca notei.

### Consoantes

> [image]
> Adaptado de [Fonologia da Língua Portuguesa (Wikipédia).](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa)

Novamente, ilustrei apenas os símbolos menos claros. Nesta tabela alguns símbolos vêm em pares: por exemplo, a plosiva bilabial, canto superior esquerdo, pode ser [p] ou [b]. Ambas são produzidas com o mesmo movimento da língua e lábios; a única diferença é que a garganta vibra para produzir o [b], mas não para o [p]. Por isso o [b] se diz *sonoro* ou *vozeado*, e o [p], *surdo* ou *não vozeado* (*voiced* e *unvoiced* em inglês). O mesmo se passa com todos os outros pares: o da esquerda é surdo, e o da direita é sonoro. A diferença é especialmente fácil de ver no caso das fricativas. Experimentem o seguinte. Ponham a ponta dos dedos na garganta e façam um ***s*** (de ***s**apo*) contínuo, depois passem sem interrupção para um ***z*** (de ***z**ona*) contínuo, e vão mudando de um som para o outro. Vão ver que a posição da boca e língua nunca muda; a única coisa que muda é que a garganta vibra para produzir o ***z*** (sonoro) e não vibra para produzir o ***s*** (surdo). O mesmo acontece quando alternam entre os sons dos outros pares. Mas nas fricativas sente-se melhor a diferença na garganta, porque conseguimos produzi-las continuamente, enquanto as restantes consoantes não conseguimos.

Comment: Vê [Wikipédia: AFI Fonologia da língua portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) e também [Wikipédia:AFI para português e galego](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia%3aAFI_para_português_e_galego).

Comment: Jacinto,   Eu nunca ouvi um espanhol pronunciar o "z" sonoro.  Tu saberias me dizer se existe esse fonema na língua espanhola?

Comment: @Centaurus Boa pergunta. Eu creio que não, e uma olhada rápida na [wikipedia sobre fonologia espanhola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology) confirma esta ideia. "Chorizo" é pronunciado ou como "chouriço" ou como "chouritho" com th de "thing".

Comment: @Centaurus o sonido [z] (do AFI) realiza-se no espanhol como alófono do fonema /s/ (respresentado pelo S) quando aparece /s/ justo antes dum sonido sonoro como na palavra *mesmo*.  Não é pronunciado sempre assim (/s/ em espanhol pode ser [s], [s̺], [z], [h], ou mudo]), nem sói ser notável para os falantes do espanhol.  Então, a letra Z, no espanhol americano onde não há distinção entre S e Z, pode ter esse sonido também.

Comment: @guifa De veras. :) “/s/ se sonoriza [z] ante consonante sonora, pudiendo ser apical [z̺] (mayor parte de España así como en los Andes centrales) o laminar [z̻] (mayor parte de Hispanoamérica); musgo [ˈmuz̺ɣ̞o̞]~[ˈmuz̻ɣ̞o̞]. Según una transcripción más o menos específica se utiliza [z], [z̺] o [z̻]. ... En otros dialectos no ocurre esta sonorización permaneciendo sorda” [ref](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_AFI#cite_note-s-11)