# Como é que "sal" está associado a "salgar" e "salgado/a"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

A palavra *[sal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_de_cozinha)* tem um verbo associado, *salgar*, relativo ao uso de sal tanto para conservar como para tempero. Da mesma forma, a palavra *salgado/a* define algo que tem sal, podendo ser usado como comparação (algo pode estar mais ou menos salgado que outra coisa). Conheço ainda a palavra *salga*, o nome da ação de salgar.

**Como surgiu a letra 'g'** de salga(r) e salgado/a? A palavra *sal* é a raiz destas palavras, ou existe uma raiz mais antiga que incluía a letra 'g'?

Comment: (Salgar também pode ser deitar sal num terreno para o tornar estéril, p.e. em contexto de guerra medieval.)

Comment: Sim, @ANeves, disseram-me que também talvez tivesse outro significado no Brasil (alguém confere?)

Comment: E obrigado, @Jacinto, pela correção.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo todos os dicionários que consultei, *salgar* não vem do português *sal*, mas sim do latim vulgar **salicare* (ver [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/salgar) ou [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=salgar); o asterisco em **salicare* significa que a palavra é conjetural e não atestada). O Dicionário da Academia Real Española indica a mesma origem para o castelhano [*salgar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X2yIIGx%7CX32qY8e) e [*salegar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X2VG9UZ%7CX2XCxj7). [*Salgado*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=salgado), [*salga*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=salga) e [*salgadeira*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=salgadeira) derivam de *salgar*.

A passagem do *c* a *g* foi relativamente comum na evolução do latim para o português. Por exemplo, *praedicare* passou a [*pregar³*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=pregar) (proferir sermões, etc); *masticare* a [*mastigar*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=mastigar); *revocare* a [*revogar*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=revogar). Até mesmo *Portugal* já foi [*Portucale*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portus_Cale). Os sons /k/ (*c* de cão) e /g/ (*g* de gato) são muito parecidos: são produzidos com a boca e língua na mesma posição; a única diferença é que a garganta vibra para produzir o /g/, mas não para o /k/ (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade/1072#1072) para mais explicações).

Comment: Este processo chama-se "sonorização".

Comment: @someonewithpc Falas da passagem do /k/ a /g/, certo?

Comment: Sim, essa nesna

Comment: Quando à queda do _i_, [Carolina Michaëlis de Vasconcellos](https://books.google.nl/books?id=eKZHAQAAMAAJ&vq=filologia%20salgar&dq=filologia%20salgar&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q&f=false) (sign in necessário para ver texto completo) diz "_Icar_, muito comum em latim vulgar, fundiu-se também com o tema, por queda do _i_ postónico, sempre que êle terminava em consoante simples. Basta lembrar os verbos _salgar_, _amargar_, _cavalgar_, _madrugar_, _julgar_, _vingar_, _outrogar_, _folgar_. Só quando havia consoantes duplas, subsiste a forma _-egar_, v.g. em _carregar_ < carricare, _sossegar_ < _sessicare_.

Comment: @bandrade o ***3*** significa entrada 3 em *pregar*. *Pregar 1* e *pregar 2* têm outras origens.

Comment: @bandrade troquei para um 3 em "superscript"; vê se achas claro assim.

Comment: @Artefacto Com consoante duplas, queres dizer quaisquer duas consoantes? Estou a pensar em *mastigar* < *masticare*. Ou será exceção? *Masticare* também nos deu *mascar*.

Comment: Muito bem, gostei também do link para o _[IPA Chart](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/)_ presente na resposta indicada!