# Transliteração de palavras em vários idiomas, para a língua portuguesa

Tags: pronúncia

Vi na Wikipédia em português, palavras de muitos idiomas com transliteração. Porém, achei um pouco difícil interpretar algumas transliterações, principalmente de palavras orientais. Quais são as regras para aprender a ler tantas transliterações diferentes, sendo que muitos sons linguísticos não existem na língua portuguesa? E, as transliterações da Wikipédia em português, são baseadas na forma como pronunciamos palavras em português, ou há outra(s) regra(s)?

Comment: É comum usar-se o alfabeto fonético internacional para mostrar a pronúncia de uma palavra (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade/1072#1072). Mas sem ver exemplos dessas transliterações, não posso ter a certeza. Não queres incluir alguns exemplos e links às tais páginas?

Answer (score 1):

Julgo que a regra principal ao fazer transliterações, antes mesmo da regra fonética apontada, e de forma muito pertinente, pelo Jacinto, é a regra que preserva a historicidade da Língua Portuguesa. Mas nem sempre.

Dou-lhe um exemplo que li em tempos e que faz referência ao topónimo **Xangai** (chinês: 上海; pinyin: Shànghǎi). É comum vermos grafado, hoje em dia em várias fontes, como **Shanghai** devido à hegemonia do Inglês, mas jamais o vemos grafado como **Changai**, que seria a grafia aplicável caso respeitássemos unicamente a regra fonética, embora saibamos que um `x` no início da uma palavra toma o som de `ch`. Todavia a grafia Xangai já aparece em registos antigos da Língua Portuguesa, e por isso usamo-la.

Outro exemplo interessante é **Moscovo**, topónimo usado na variante europeia do Português para a capital da Federação Russa (em russo: Москва, transl Moskva, lido Maskvá). Poderíamos ter grafado "Mosquevá", todavia não existe qualquer `e` sonoro entre `k` e o `á`, logo a regra fonética também não nos ajudaria. Recorde-se, portanto, que a palavra **Moscovo** é a que mais se assemelha foneticamente ao russo [maskvá], mas o topónimo em questão não entrou no Português pelo russo, entrou, sim, pelo francês **Moscou**. Outrora, era essa a forma usada em Portugal, que evoluiu para Moscovo, mas que se manteve no Brasil. Neste caso, em Portugal prevaleceu a regra fonética, enquanto no Brasil e regra etimológica.

Em qualquer caso, a regra mais pertinente nos tempos correntes, é não usarmos formas silábicas existentes em Inglês mas inexistentes em Português, como `Sh` para Xangai; ou `ing` para "Beijing", cada [vez mais usado](https://www.google.nl/search?safe=active&biw=1058&bih=543&tbm=nws&ei=h0_XW6qMMY-ysAferaKgDA&q=Beijing%20not%C3%ADcias&oq=Beijing%20not%C3%ADcias&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4034.4828.0.5051.5.5.0.0.0.0.54.185.4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.s9urQFIFhDY).