# Porque é que no meu sotaque “ganho” não rima com “banho”?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia

Em Portugal, muitas pessoas, entre as quais eu me incluo, pronunciam aberto o á de *g**a**nho;* como em *j**á***; ou /'gaɲu/ em alfabeto fonético internacional (AFI; podem ver a chave [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade)). Mas há pessoas em Portugal que o pronunciam fechado, como em *sop**a***, ou /'gɐɲu/ em AFI. Na verdade eu só reparei nesta segunda pronúncia recentemente, e até a estranho. Mas devo ter andado muito distraído: hoje almocei com um colega de há uma data de anos, e ele pronuncia /'gɐɲu/, com o á fechado. A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ganhar) regista as duas pronúncias; o dicionário da Academias das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), só a minha. Estas duas pronúncias estendem-se ao á correspondente da família *ganhar*.

Agora, o que me faz espécie que, ao contrário de *ganho*, *banho* eu pronuncio /'bɐɲu/, com o á fechado; e o mesmo com o á de palavras semelhantes: *anho, banho, lanho, ranho*, etc. Os dicionários concordam: para estas outras palavras só indicam a pronúncia com á fechado. Tirando as palavras da família de *ganhar*, não me lembro de nenhum outro caso do á de -***a***nh-, tónico ou não, pronunciado aberto.

Então a minha pergunta é: **existe alguma explicação inteligível para o que parece ser a pronúncia excecional de *ganho* e família?**

Nota: parece-me que esta questão não se coloca no Brasil, mas os colegas brasileiros me corrigirão se for caso disso. (Também podem confirmar, n’é?) De qualquer modo, de acordo com o Portal da Língua Portuguesa, no Rio e em São Paulo [*ganho*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=23309&highlight=%5Eganho$) rima sempre com [*banho*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=106010&highlight=%5Ebanho$), à semelhança do que se passa com o resto das respetivas famílias.

Comment: Pior: eu definitivamente digo "este amplificador tem pouco gãnho" como "tomei um bãnho", mas digo "ontem gánhei eu". E acho que digo "este gãnho eu".

Comment: @ANeves, pior?! Eu vejo um padrão nesses teus exemplos: é ã quando é tónico, seja da famíla *ganhar*, seja na *banhar*; e é á qando é átono. Presumivelmente dizes *gánhar* e *gánhava*. Segundo o Portal da Língua Portuguesa, os cariocas também pronuncia com ã, mas em todas as palavras.

Comment: @ANeves, então, e dizes *bánhei, bânhei* ou *bãnhei?*

Comment: Digo "bãnhei", "bãnha-te", "bãnho". Disse pior, porque me pareceu que conjugo o verbo ganhar todo com /ga/, menos a primeira pessoa do presente do indicativo que por alguma razão vira /gɐ/. Mas agora já repeti isto tantas vezes na minha cabeça, que não sei nada.

Comment: @ANeves, então e *ganha, ganhe* e *ganham?* Tou a tentar ver se é só primeira pessoa do singular ou se é sempre que é tónico.

Comment: Hmm... ele gãnha, que ele gãnhe, eles gãnham.

Comment: @ANeves, então lá está: nos dois verbos, *ganhar* e *banhar*, pronuncias ã sempre que é tónico. Provavelmente também em *apanhar, arranha*, etc. E pensando bem, eu parece-me que nasá-lo um bocadito o á tónico nesses verbos, exceto no *ganhar*.

Comment: Normalmente isto acontece quando houve crase de duas vogais, como em geração (gene-), corar (colo-), etc.

Comment: @Rui, terá sido isso neste caso? Também já me tinha perguntado porquê que o **e** de geração é aberto.

Comment: O dicionário da Academica segue a pronúncia de Lisboa. Tenho ideia de que pronunciar esse _a_ fechado é mais uma coisa do norte. [Aqui o Pinto da Costa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALaxIJQgCVc) pronuncia _ganhámos_ com os dois _a_ fechados, em Lisboa seriam os dois abertos.

Comment: @Artefacto, isso confere com o o que diz o ANeves lá em cima: ã ha de ser fechado. Esse meu amigo que pronuncia com à fechado está há muito tempo (décadas) em Lisboa, mas ele é originalmente de Chaves (para os brasileiros, é no norte).

Comment: De acordo com a Infopédia, os 4 outros exemplos que você dá (anho, banho, lanho, ranho) vêm diretamente do latim, enquanto "ganho" viria pelo francês. Poderia ser essa a diferença?

Comment: @stafusa, quem sabe se tem que ver com isso?

Comment: Eu acho que digo todas as palavras "...anho" da mesma forma.

Comment: @JorgeB., ao que parece é o pessoal de Lisboa e sul (eu sou de Torres Vedras, a norte de Lisboa, mas que dialeticalmente é sul) que diz *banho* e família diferentemente das outras "...anho". Vê o que dizem o Artefacto e ANeves acima.

Comment: @Artefacto, mas eu tenho ouvido também g[ɐ]nhar a uns comentadores de futebol que pelo sotaque não parecem ser do norte (no canal Sport TV +); se calhar isto está a alastrar. Também já ouvi pessoal dizer g[ɨ]ração, e creio que eram cá de baixo. Não se são as mesmas pessoas que dizem g[ɐ]nhar e g[ɨ]ração.

Answer (score 5):

Ofereci aqui uma bounty, e ninguém pegou na pergunta, de maneira que segui a dica do Rui Fonseca acima, e bingo: nos séculos XIII e XIV era *g**aa**nho* e *g**aa**nhar*. Obviamente a sequência **aa** fundiu-se num único **a** (uma crase), e, explica o [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vogais-atonas-abertas/23284), o **a** que resulta da crase de dois aa tende em sotaques comuns em Portugal a manter timbre aberto, mesmo em posições em que esperaríamos timbre fechado. O mesmo acontece com o **o** resultante da crase de dois oo (mantém timbre aberto em vez de reduzir para [u] e com o **e** resultante de dois ee (mantém timbre aberto em vez de reduzir para [ɨ] ou desaparecer). Estas vogais duplas resultaram tipicamente do desaparecimento de certas consoantes que no latim havia entre elas, mais comumente o **l** e o **n**, mas também o **d** e o **g**.

O [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vogais-atonas-abertas/23284) apresenta o exemplo de *g*aa*nhar* > *g**a**nhar* e ainda os seguintes (as explicações são minhas, baseadas no que lá está):

> *C**a**veira* vem de *c**aa**veira* no português antigo, que vem do latim *c**ala**varia*. O **l** intervocálico caiu, fenómeno comum na evolução do latim para o português, deixando dois aa com hiato entre eles, até que se fundiram num só. Aquele primeiro **a** de *c**a**veira* tem timbre aberto, contrastando com o timbre fechado típico da posição pretónica, como o primeiro **a** de *cr**a**veira, l**a**deira, **a**lheira, br**a**seira*.
>
> ***A**veiro* < ***Aa**veiro* < ***Ala**veiro*. É uma cidade portuguesa, um caso parecidíssimo com o de *caveira*.
>
> *C**o**rado* < *c**oo**rado* no português antigo < *c**olo**rado* no latim. Mesmo fenómeno evolutivo de *caveira*. O **o** inicial de *c**o**rado* é aberto, enquanto naquela posição, pretónica, é normalmente reduzido a [u], como em *ad**o**rado, r**o**sado, c**o**lado*.
>
> *Pr**e**gar* (um sermão; não um prego) < *pr**ee**gar* < *pr**aedi**care*. O **e** é aberto, enquanto naquela posição se reduz normalmente para [ɨ] ou é elidido completamente, como em *pr**e**gar* (um prego), *r**e**gar, v**e**dar, l**e**var*.
>
> *Esqu**e**cer* < *esqu**ee**cer* < *esc**ae**cer* < **exc**aede**scer.* O **e** inicial aberto contrasta com a redução para [ɨ] ou elisão, como em *per**e**cer, rec**e**ber, m**e**ter*.

Depois fui ao dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), que indica formas antigas das palavras, ver outras palavras com timbres aberto “anómalos”, e não falha (a formas intermédias entre o português moderno e o latim são as registadas no Houaiss, todas de entre os séculos XIII e XV):

> *P**a**deiro* < *p**aa**deiro* < *pada* (pequeno pão) +*-eiro*; Por sua vez, *p**a**da* < latim *p**ana**ta*.
>
> *S**a**dio* < *s**aad**ya*  < *s**ana**tivus*
>
> *V**a**dio* < *v**aa**dios, u**aa**dios* < *v**aga**tivus*
>
> *P**e**gada* (marca deixada pelo pé) < *p**ee**gadas* < *p**edi**cata*. No português antigo temos também *pees* (pés) do latim *pedis*; agora percebo porque é o meu pai dizia *péis* em vez de *pés* (ele não era brasileiro). Ao contrário do **e** aberto de *p**e**gada* (do pé), o **e** de *p**e**gada* de *pegar* reduz-se a [ɨ].
>
> *G**e**ração* < *g**ee**raçõ, g**ee**raçom* < *g**ene**ratio,onis*. O mesmo com *g**e**rador* < *g**ee**rador, j**ee**rador* < *g**ene**rator*. Mas também temos no português antigo *geerar* e *geeral*, mas no moderno o **e** é reduzido: *g[ɨ]rar* e *g[ɨ]ral*.

E nem os sobrenomes escapam. Temos o primeiro **a** “anomalamente” aberto em *T**a**vares* e *T**a**veira*, e basta ir ao Google Books para encontrarmos *T**aa**vares* e *T**aa**veira*. O filólogo José Leite Vasconcellos diz que há registo de *Thalavares* e presume que tenha havido *Talaveira* ([*Lições de Filologia Portuguesa*, 1911](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2AwBAAAAMAAJ&q=taavares&dq=taavares&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikksb5reLiAhWJ8eAKHffcBKEQ6AEIODAC), e outra página de uma [edição de 1926](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kVlfAAAAMAAJ&q=taaveira&dq=taaveira&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNlu2wreLiAhWR3OAKHSsrDUIQ6AEIODAC)).

Esta coisa de a crase abrir o timbre observa-se presentemente no sotaque de Portugal. A preposição ***a*** e o artigo definido ***a*** têm timbre fechado em Portugal, mas a crase deles, ***à***, tem timbre aberto. O mesmo acontece com as crases (não assinaladas graficamente) resultantes do encadeamento de palavras na fala: por exemplo, os **aa** de *bol**a*** e ***a**zul* têm em Portugal timbre fechado quando as palavras são pronunciadas isoladas, mas *bola azul* é pronunciado como *bol**a**zul* com o **a** com timbre abeto.