# No Brasil, "pra a" e "pra" são falados da mesma maneira?

Tags: preposições, dialetos, fonética

Para facilitar a compreensão e porque eu considero a forma que deveria ser correta, "prà" = "pra a". Eu sou brasileiro, então, pode ser algo dialetal.

Em "quero ir pra Goiás", *pra* tende a ser mais fechada e talvez menos tónica do que *prà* em "quero ir prà praia". A diferença não é suficiente para distinção óbvia entre "pra" e "prà"; digo, se eu falasse todos os "prà(s)"s como "pra" e todos os "pra(s)"s como "prà(s)"s, não soaria incorreto, mas eu não falaria assim. O mesmo acontece com "parà" e "para" (*parà* = *para a*); na realidade, com bem mais força com "parà" e "para".

O mesmo também ocorre com "à" e "a". Em "às 6:00" e "vou a igrejas", *às* parece ser mais tônico e aberto do que *a*.

Pelo que sei, em Portugal, "prà" e "pra" são falados diferentemente. Mas seria o caso disso, no Brasil? Ou seria algo exclusivamente dialetal?

Comment: Sabes bem: em Portugal esse *prà* (= *pra a*) tem timbre aberto (á), enquanto só *pra* tem timbre fechado (â). Isso não acontece só com *pra*. Sempre que dois ás fechados átonos se encontra, eles fundem-se num único á aberto. Por exemplo, a preposição *a* e o artigo feminino *a* têm ambos timbre fechado, mas *à* (*a + a*) tem timbre aberto;  *lev**a** luz* tem timbre fechado, mas *lev**a a** luz* soa como *lev**à** luz*, com timbre aberto. Estou curioso para saber se existe uma diferença parecida algures no Brasil.

Comment: @Jacinto, em encontro de dois As átonos, isso também ocorre, eu acho. Mas entre "pra" e "prà", e entre "a" e "à", tenho minhas dúvidas. Eu devia ter incluído "a" e "à" também.

Comment: @Jacinto, eu tenho minhas dúvidas em relação ao Brasil, não em relação a Portugal. Eu escrevi mal.

Comment: Compreendi. Historicamente, todos estes aa resultam de fusão  Antigamente, escrevia-se *aa* em vez de *à*; imagino que se pronunciassem os dois aa. Os portugueses tenderam a fechar o timbre dos aa átonos, mas não dos que resultaram de fusão. Isso vê-se mesmo no interior de palavras (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5738/porque-%c3%a9-que-no-meu-sotaque-ganho-n%c3%a3o-rima-com-banho)). Por exemplo, em Portugal o primeiro a de *p**a**deira* é "anormalmente" aberto (ao contrário de *l**a**deira, m**a**deira*) e no português antigo era como? *P**aa**deira.*

Comment: @Jacinto, não sei se pronunciavam os dois As em "aa" (= "à"), mas sei que era comum dobrar vogais para mostrar vogal aberta; ex.: "moor" em vez de "mor" para indicar "mór".

Comment: @Jacinto, porque lat. "Solus" → pt. "Solo" → "soo", sendo "oo" um hiato com ambos os Os fechados, → "só", agora "o" aberto. Por isso era comum escrever vogais dobradas para indicar vogal aberta.

Comment: @Jacinto, pelo que sei, essa mudança aconteceu entre 1500-1550 (até que bem rápido), então, essa mudança provavelmente chegou ao Brasil. Mas o Brasil não diferencia vogal A aberta e vogal A fechada, então, "à' é diferente de "a" preposição. Por isso achei que fosse algo dialetal.

Comment: Creio que estás a fazer uma confusão qualquer e a projetar a pronúncia atual no português medieval. Dizes bem, " 'soo' sendo 'oo' um hiato". O hiato é uma separação entre os dois oo: os dois *oo* eram pronunciados com um hiato entre eles, após a queda do l em *solo*. O teu raciocínio anterior aplicado a *dolor → door → dor* concluiria que dois oo indicavam ô fechado! A Gramática do Português da Gulbenkian diz que estes hiatos desapareceram no século XV. Que mudança ocorreu em 1500-1550?

Comment: @Jacinto, eu devo ter me confundido XV, que é 15, com século XV, que é 1400. Desculpa, o livro que li piora quando chega nessa parte e eu me confundi com a data. Mas vários hiatos se transformaram em uma só vogal aberta, porém ou "dor" é uma exceção ou o meu livro não explica. Desculpa.

Comment: @Jacinto, peço-te mil perdões. O livro fala sobre um hiato se transformando em apenas 1 vogal, esta aberta, estando esse hiato EM POSIÇÃO PRETÓNICA. Por exemplo, "esquecer", que o penúltimo "e" é aberto, em português de Portugal, pelo menos. Um dos "o"s em "coor" era tônico, então, "o" em "cor" não é aberto. Desculpa, de novo.

Comment: Não é preciso pedir desculpa. A questão fundamental é que as vogais dobradas, *aa, oo, ee* (*general →  geeral*) representavam duas vogais pronunciadas com hiato entre elas, não um única vogal. Depois fundiram-se numa única e passaram a ser representadas por um única vogal. É verdade, em *door, coor*, uma vogal é tónica. Exceção nas pretónicas, tens *geeral  → geral, geerar  → gerar*, com e pronunciado [ɨ] (quase sumido, não existe no Brasil), mas *geeração → g**e**ração* com é aberto.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do que consigo perceber, não há diferença alguma, ao menos nos dialetos com que me considero mais familiar (caipira, sulista e paulistano). Então, eu diria que a diferença que o OP descreve não é predominante em pt-BR.