# A língua Portuguesa já teve vogais longas no passado?

Tags: mudanças-históricas, linguística

No passado *maçã* e *pá* eram escritas *“maçãa”* e *“paa”*. Essas vogais eram longas? Ou eram vogais distintas, ocorridas em sílabas separadas (como em *“micro-ondas, voo e cooperar”*)?

Não me refiro às vogais longas do Latim, como as que haviam em *“sōbrīnus”* (sobrinho), essas se perderam antes da Língua Portuguesa sequer existir. Refiro-me às vogais que eram escritas duplas, tanto orais quanto nasais, formadas pela deleção do /n/ intervocálico (como explico [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/como-%c3%a9-que-una-e-unus-do-latim-deram-em-uma-e-um-no-portugu%c3%aas)) e do /l/ ou /d/ intervocálico.

Na tabela abaixo explico a evolução fonética e ortográfica que ocorreu com a deleção dos `/n/` e `/l,d/` intervocálicos. (GL-PT significa “Galego-Português”, outro nome para “Português antigo”).

```
=====EVOLUÇÃO FONÉTICA====  =====EVOLUÇÃO ORTOGRÁFICA=====
LATINO > GL-PT > PORTUGUÊS  LATINO   > GL-PT  > PORTUGUÊS

/-a.na > -ãa?  > -ã/       ⟨mattiana > maçãa  > maçã⟩
/-o.no > -õo?  > -õ/       ⟨bonus    > bõo    > bom⟩
/-e.ne > -ẽe?  > -ẽ/       ⟨tenet    > tẽe    > tem⟩
/-a.la > -aa?  > -a/       ⟨pala     > paa    > pá⟩
/-o.lo > -oo?  > -ɔ/       ⟨solus    > soo    > só⟩
/-o.do > -oo?  > -ɔ/       ⟨nodus    > noo    > nó⟩
/-e.de > -ee?  > -ɛ/       ⟨sedes    > see    > sé⟩
```

Existe alguma gramática da época que ateste sobre a qualidade dessas vogais?
A língua Portuguesa já teve, por um certo período de tempo, vogais longas tais como no Latim Clássico?
Noutras palavras, como *maçãa* e *paa* eram pronunciadas?

Comment: O Wikcionário, no verbete [*“poo”* (pó)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poo#Old_Portuguese), que veio do Latim Vulgar “pulus” (que por sua vez veio do Latim Clássico “pulvus”, cognato de “pulverizar”), diz que a pronúncia era `/ˈpɔ.o/`, com duas vogais em sílabas separadas (em vez de uma única vogal longa numa única sílaba). Mas não há fontes. Este verbete está correto?

Comment: Interessante que, segundo o Wikcionário, além de “*poo*” ter vogais diferentes, em sílabas diferentes, elas têm qualidades diferentes: uma é aberta (`/ɔ/`) e a outra é fechada (`/o/`).

Comment: A Gramática da Gulbenkian diz que no português antigo eram hiatos, mas que despareceram no sXV. Agora, essas vogais duplas deixaram vestígios no português europeu atual. Exemplo, enquanto o **a** de *c**a**deira* se fechou, o de *p**a**deira* (*paadeira* no português antigo) continuou aberto (mais exemplos [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5738/porque-%c3%a9-que-no-meu-sotaque-ganho-n%c3%a3o-rima-com-banho)). Como esse fechamento no *c**a**deira* e similares aconteceu já depois do sXV (não ocorreu no Brasil), alguma coisa desses *aa, ee* etc. teve de >>

Comment: >> sobreviver para bloquear o fechamento em *padeira* e outras que tinham essas vogais duplas. Terão entre hiato e vogal simples passado por vogal longa? Agora, eu tou a ler a Ortografia da Língua Portuguesa do Duarte Nunes de Leão (1576) e ele continua a escrever com vogais duplas! O problema é que ele é muito confuso. Diz que não há nas vogais distinção longa-breve, mas não diz como pronuncia as duplas.

Answer (score 1):

Não, o que se representa no galego-português com duas vogais, como em "paaço", é um hiato deixado pela síncope de uma consoante, assim esta dita palavra tem três sílabas: pa-a-ço, sendo o segundo "a" tônico (o mesmo que era tônico no latim). Este hiato posteriormente foi simplificado.

O ancestral mais recente no qual se encontram vogais longas é o latim mesmo. Inclusive, no próprio latim vulgar o sistema de quantidade de vogais já estava gradualmente se tornando um sistema que distingue a qualidade das vogais (como o "ē" tornando-se [e] e o "ĕ" tornando-se "[ɛ]" etc), e que gerou a mudança de timbre e as ditongações que ocorreram em línguas como o espanhol e o italiano.