# Tem "ontem" um o aberto?

Tags: pronúncia

Estava mexendo na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ontem) e no [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=90179), e percebi uma coisa curiosa: a pronúncia de *ontem* é õtãe/õtẽi, como o fechado. Mas me soa esquisito falar *ontem* com o fechado e não aberto.

Então pergunto: “ontem” tem o aberto ou fechado? Isto é, se *ontem* é falado /ˈõn-/ ou /ˈɔ̃n-/. Se fizer sentido, há alguma relação com *homem* ter o aberto nalgumas regiões e não noutras?

Comment: Pena não se poder pôr aqui registos áudio:   nunca vi um /ɔ̃/ em lado nenhum, nem consigo muito bem imaginar como seja...

Comment: Não entendo: aonde você **ouviu** tudo isso?

Comment: @Lambie, primeiro quando eu vi a pronúncia com o fechado no Portal da Língua, eu tentei pronunciar, e aí percebi que eu falava aberto. Porém, por garantia, fui perguntar a alguém, então, liguei para alguém e o fiz falar *ontem* sem eu ter falado *ontem*. Aí percebi que ele também falava aberto.

Comment: @Jacinto, se achares um paulista (do estado de São Paulo) falando *homem*, *come* (comer) ou *some* (sumir), provavelmente verás um /ɔ̃/. Falo *paulista* porque não sei do resto e já ouvi que, no Brasil, o aberto em *homem* é coisa de paulista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo Albano e Barbosa, o ó nasal de São Paulo é intermédio entre “aberto” e “fechado”. Vejam a figura abaixo que eu adaptei da [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) (os símbolos são do alfabético fonético internacional; podem escutá-los [aqui](https://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm) ou ver uma ilustração simples [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade))

[image]

Nós gostamos de classificar as vogais simplesmente entre abertas e fechada, mas tecnicamente os nossos ós “aberto” (como em *av**ó***) e “fechado” (*av**ô***) são apenas dois pontos num contínuo que vai do /ɒ/, que não existe no português, até ao /u/. Tecnicamente, o nosso ó é semiaberto, e nosso ô é semifechado. Enquanto o ó nasal de Lisboa é igualmente semifechado, o de São Paulo, segundo Albano e Barbos citados na [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa), é intermédio entre semiaberto e semifechado.

Eu fui ouvir uns tantos ós nasais no Forvo, e de facto, enquanto a maioria os pronuncia como eu julgo que eu pronuncio (“fechado”), há uns tantos que me parecem pronunciá-los um nadinha mais abertos. Ouçam a Sirasp pronunciar [*ontem*](https://forvo.com/word/ontem/#pt), [*conta*](https://forvo.com/word/conta/#pt) ou [*ponto*](https://forvo.com/word/ponto/#pt), e comparem com os outros falantes lá. Mas a diferença, se não é apenas imaginação minha, é muito subtil. Eu em conversa jamais notaria.

Comment: Jacinto. fui no Forvo e acho que percebi que a Siraspa fala tal como eu nas palavras que citaste. E com alguns testes ***científicos*** fonéticos pessoais, acho que estás certíssimo. Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Na falta de uma resposta desde a postagem da pergunta, compartilho minhas meras impressões pessoais.

Considero que na maioria dos dialetos, em pt-BR ao menos, a nasalização trazida pelo "n" torna o "o" fechado.
Os seis exemplos do [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/ontem/) e das pessoas a minha volta me soam mais fechados que abertos (inclusive de pt-PT), mas também não 100% fechados. Penso que minha pronúncia em particular, embora fechada, possa ficar ligeiramente próxima de aberta quando falo a palavra isolada, e mais fechada ainda quando numa frase.

Comment: Para além de tentar ler as tabelas na wikipedia ainda estou a tentar perceber isto das vogais abertas, fechadas, etc... Sempre que começo a aprender um pouco de fonologia mudo de assunto e quando volto já não me lembro do que aprendi antes.

Comment: Para mim os ós nasais também soam todos fechados. Em Portugal são de certeza. Aliás todas as vogais nasais o são. Agora, a nossa mente dicotómica gosta de dividir as vogais entre abertas e fechadas, mas na verdade creio que á um contínuo com infinitos graus de abertura/fechamento.