# Ao usar a palavra "Inter", quando devo colocar hífen?

Tags: ortografia, hífen

**Por exemplo:**

> Intercâmbio (não possui hífen)
>
> Inter-humano (possui hífen)

A pergunta é: Quando eu devo colocar o hífen ao usar a palavra `Inter`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No caso, se enquadra na regra 1 abaixo. São as regras de uso do hífen, em resumo.

## Regra 1: Antes do H

A letra “H” é uma letra sem personalidade, sem som. Em “Hermes”, não tem som; em "Halloween”, tem som de “R”. Portanto, não deve aparecer encostado em prefixos:

- pré-história
- anti-higiênico
- sub-hepático
- super-homem

## Regra 2: Separar Letras Iguais

- Anti-inflamatório
- Supra-auricular
- Arqui-inimigo

## Regra 3: Prefixos Terminados em Consoante

- Sub-reino
- ab-rogar
- sob-roda

## Regra 4: “pós-, pré- e pró-“

- pós-tônico
- pré-escolar
- pré-natal
- pró-labore
- pró-africano
- pró-europeu
- pós-graduação

## Regra 5: Diante de “pan-, circum-", Quando Juntos de Vogais

- pan-americano
- circum-escola

[Tirei a informação daqui](http://www.abril.com.br/reforma-ortografica/hifen.shtml).

Se não entrar em nenhuma dessas regras, escreve-se o termo junto, sem hífen (caso de "Intercâmbio").

Comment: Ah, então no meu caso, eu utilizo o hífen na palavra `Inter-Humano` pois a palavra `humano` começa com `h` e não o utilizo na palavra `Intercâmbio` porque a mesma não se enquadra nas regras?

Comment: Sim. Se não entrar em nenhuma dessas regras, escreve-se junto sempre.

Comment: Em Portugal na palavra *Halloween* o **h** também não tem som.

Comment: A regra 5 desconheço, não sei se é usada em Portugal.

Comment: `em "Halloween”, tem som de “R”` ai :( Mais seriamente: como pode o h ser "uma letra sem personalidade, sem som" e ao mesmo tempo ter som de r? Proponho que removas o exemplo estrangeiro "Halloween".

Comment: @JorgeB. eu também desconhecia, mas é usada em Portugal: http://priberam.pt/dlpo/pan-

Comment: +1, Comentário à regra 5: segundo o [Acordo Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa (1990)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=vop&&page=crit2), citado em http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/, o hífen é usado após prefixos quando estes terminam por <n> ou <m> e a palavra a que se juntam começa com uma dessas consoantes ou com vogal: pan-nacional. (http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/323/105).