# Porque é que co-autor passou para coautor com o AO?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

Porque é que [co-autor](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/coautor) passou para coautor com o Acordo Ortográfico?

Não deveria ser como co-utente e co-herdeiro?

[A regra não deveria usar hífen?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/323/153)

Comment: Me parece uma duplicata da outra pergunta, visto que a resposta da outra explica com detalhe que seria *coautora*, *coutente* (não **co-utente*), e *co-herdeiro*. O dicionário Priberam concorda: veja por exemplo [coutente](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/coutente).

Comment: @DanGetz eu próprio linkei essa resposta, e como podes facilmente reparar não responde à minha pergunta.

Comment: @DanGetz tens razão é duplicata eu é que entendi mal a regra.