# O que significa "re" no começo das palavras?

Tags: gramática

O que significa "re" no começo das palavras, como em "reagir", "reator", etc.? Sempre significa que é algo que acontece novamente?

Ainda existem casos em que devemos usar o hífen, como no antigo caso da palavra "re-estabelecer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em geral, [sim](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/re-):

> *re-* [do latim]: prefixo que exprime a ideia de repetição, intensidade, reciprocidade e movimento para trás",

embora "reator", por exemplo, tenha vindo através do inglês ou francês.

Sobre o hífen, há mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/323/2764), mas também sim, poderá haver casos, como o da repetição do "e" na junção das duas palavras, em que se usa um hífen, mas apenas para neologismos, uma vez que:

> O hífen é usado após estes elementos [...] **exceto** no caso de palavras formadas com prefixos átonos como des-, in- e re- que já se justapunham, antes da aplicação do AO, sem hífen

portanto, "reencarnar", "reescrever" e todas as palavras que encontrei dicionarizadas (ver também [aqui](https://umportugues.com/prefixo-re)) não contém o hífen após o "re".

Já para o nome "Renan", nenhuma das muitas origens [listadas](https://www.dicionariodenomesproprios.com.br/renan/) incluiria o latim o prefixo "re":

> **Renan**: Significa “amigo”, “companheiro”; “misterioso”; “foca”.
>
> É um nome com diversas possibilidades de origem. Uma das mais aceitas indica que o nome tenha surgido a partir da raiz celta ron, que quer dizer “amigo” ou “companheiro”.
>
> Pode também ter surgido do germânico Runant, que deriva no termo run que quer dizer “mistério”. Nesse sentido, por extensão, o nome significa “misterioso”.
>
> Na língua francesa, Renan é derivado de Ronan. Ronan é o diminutivo da palavra ron, que significaria literalmente “foca”. O nome é utilizado no sentido figurado como “aquele que é companheiro”.
>
> Ainda existem algumas fontes que relacionam a origem de Renan ao hebraico Raanan, que quer dizer “florescente” ou “luxuriante.